# Update image on input src change angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to show a photo when someone selects it for an input. Now I might be over simplyfying angularjs too much but I was hoping that this code would work.

```
    <div ng-app="app">

    ... html stuff ...

    <div ng-controller="imgCtrl">

    <input ng-model="imageSource" type="file"></input>   
    <img ng-src="{|imageSource|}"></img>

    </div>

    </div> end of app
```

Where my angularjs file is as follows

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{|');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('|}');
    }
);

var imgCtrl = function ($scope,$http){
    $scope.wall = _wall;
};

clientDashboard.controller('imgCtrl',imgCtrl);
```

Unfortunately, nothing is happening and I can't see my updated image. Do I really have to write boiler plate code for this?

Comment: What are the `|`s for in `{|imageSource|}`?

Comment: he changed the markup from `{{` `}}` to `{|` `|}`

Comment: I'm using a templating system called twig that comes with my php framework. I needed to change the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working in chrome and firefox but my quick research shows that it is a security risk and may not even be allowed eventually. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/28ZJw/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="imgCtrl">
    <input ng-model="imageSource" type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChaged(this)"></input>
    <img ng-src="{|imageSource|}"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{|');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('|}');
    }
);

app.controller('imgCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.imageSource = "";
    $scope.fileNameChaged = function(element)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            $scope.$apply(function()
            {
                $scope.imageSource = e.target.result;
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }
});
```

The right way would be to get this going with `ng-change` however I couldn't get it to work. I am not sure if `ng-change` applies to file input fields

Comment: Ya I tried doing it with ng-change as well. Technically you're suppose to 'invent' your own directive to handle this. Unfortunately that takes time and effort that I don't even want to deal with, considering I've been working on this project long enough and just started learning Angular. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah I would turn it into a directive for sure. I just started making little widgets using directives yesterday so I am not confident enough to make that a directive yet. I'm new too

Comment: here's a directive that might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Comment: there ya go, that is slick