# Angular/Breeze: how to upload images to EF database and show in html?

Tags: image, entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I know there is ngUpload directive for uploading images, and I can save the uploaded images to a file in server and save a link to database. Then, I can use the link to show it in html.

However, I'd like to save the image to database directly. In this case, how do I show the image in html?

For example, at server I have

```
public class ImgSrc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use ngUpload to upload an image and save it as an Image to this table?
How can I show the image in html using Angular?

My project is based on Breeze/Angular todo sample. It would be great if someone can add this capability to the Todo project.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to upload the image at all.  This can be handled by Breeze.

I would recommend first getting the imageData into a base64 string.  You can use [this directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063046/428972) to get the base64 data from `<input fileupload="ImgSrc.Image" type="file"/>`.  Breeze will handle the upload of the base64 string and the mapping on the Server side.  If you're using EF Code first, the `byte[] Image` property will become a `Varbinary(Max)` column in SQL Server.