# Model in input doesn't always get updated if the type is file

Tags: angularjs

I am using HTML5's file selector with AngularJS (I know the input with file type is not supported in Angularjs and I hacked a bit.), the file name will not get cleared for the 2nd upload. Any idea why??

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input ng-model="myFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onchange(this.files)" type="file" />
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module("app", []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.onchange = function (files) {
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            //doing some stuff here
            console.log(e)

            //finally clear the file for new selection
            $scope.myFile = null; // <------- doesn't clear after the 2nd file upload
            $scope.$apply();
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    };
}
```

### How to reproduce?

Go to the jsfiddle and upload the same file twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/9sdTX/

I am not processing today somehow. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/

Comment: @aheld This doesn't answer my question. My question is relating to the button issue not the file uploading.