# get the file from ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, fileapi

**How to convert this to angular.js compitable so that i get the dataurl and send through $http.post**

```
<input type="file" id="imgfiles" name="imgfiles" accept="image/jpeg" onchange="readURL(this);">


function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files[0].size <= 1048576) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#cam_photo').attr('src', e.target.result).width(250).height(230);
                var a = $('#cam_photo').attr('src');
                data_url = a;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    } else {
        alert('File is too large. Upload file less than 1MB');
    }
}
```

Comment: for example see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `angular.element(this).scope()` to get the scope

Try this:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().readURL(this)"
```

And then, write your `$scope.readURL(input)` code in your controller

```
$scope.readURL = function(input) {
    if (input.files[0].size <= 1048576) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#cam_photo').attr('src', e.target.result).width(250).height(230);
                var a = $('#cam_photo').attr('src');
                data_url = a;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    } else {
        alert('File is too large. Upload file less than 1MB');
    }
}
```