# AngularJS: upload and post photo as multi-part form data and get response

Tags: angularjs

I want to upload an image and post it to my server which should post the image further on to some API and get its response.

I could probably use view with something like:

```
<form ng-submit="updatePhoto(myphoto)"> 
    <p>Choose Photo:</p>
    <input type="file" ng-model="myphoto">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

and then in the controller the function would have something like:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'myAPIserver.php/',
        data: "myPhoto=" + photo,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
});
```

But this is not correct and I am not sure how to accomplish this. The catch is that I am sending this photo to my PHP proxy first and from there I use curl to make direct API requests.

I hope I was clear enough. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this with the help of custom directive that I got [here](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs). 
You need a custom directive for file upload if you want to access files (ngModel wont work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file) for more info).

Using first link:

```
<form ng-submit="updateSth()" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" file-model="fileToUpload" />
    <input name="somethingINeed" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

you can access the uploaded file with $scope.fileToUpload now, which makes everything easier. 
I extracted the function from the service given on the first link and didn't use it as a service since it suited me better this way …