# AngularJS - Why is <input type=file name="files" onFileSelect($files)/> not included in scope form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm not really sure if this has already been answered since I really can't find the answer in other posts.

I have an array of file names `(ex. [flower.jpg, rose.jpg])` that I want to validate against the chosen files from the input type=file form. This validation detects duplicates then I want to set the error validity like this "$scope.detailsForm.files.$setValidity("duplicate", true);".

The problem is `"$scope.detailsForm.files"` is getting undefined but this is not the case with other input types such as "`input type="text" name="username""`.

What I've noticed using AngularJS Batarang I am seeing that the scope for the `"detailsForm"` contains all my inputs' "name" attribute except for my input `type="file"`

Also what's weird is adding `"ng-model='anythingHere'"` to my input `type="file"` makes the `"name"` attribute exist in the `"detailsForm"` scope, thus achieving my desired result.

However it really is bugging me because I really don't want to add the ng-model directive since I'm already using angular-file-upload for this.

Here's a snippet of the codes:

Controller:

```
if (imageArr.indexOf(uploadFilename) != -1) {
   $scope.detailsForm.files.$setValidity("duplicate", true);
   return;
}
else {
   $scope.detailsForm.files.$setValidity("duplicate", false);
}
```

HTML:

```
input  type="file" name="files" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)
```

Hope you understand my question and situation.

PS: This is actually my first time posting here in stackOverFlow since the posts here has always answered my questions. This time I really need help! Masters I need chu!

Comment: Thanks cbass I just started learning how to format posts :D

Comment: It's simply not implemented in AngularJS. Here are some workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Comment: So that's why hehe thank you so much Sergiu