# Save Image in JSON for Rest

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, image, rest

I am currently coding on a project for school, which should be a picture sharing website.
Spring Framework is handling the database as well as the rest interface. On the rest interface I have a RemoteImage, which represents an Image saved in the Database. I also have Getters, Setters and Cunstructors in there, but did not copied it in here.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RemoteImage {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String contentType;
private byte[] content;
private Date createdAt;
private String owner;
private String camera;
private String lens;
private String aperture;
private String focalLength;
private String shutterSpeed;
private String ISO;
private String description;
private Long ownerId;
private Long categoryId;
....
```

In the Rest Resource I have the addImage function which converts the RemoteImage from the Rest into a Image for storing in the Database. The RemoteImage does not contain votes.

```
@POST
@Transactional
public void addImage(RemoteImage remoteImage) {
    try {
        Image image = new Image(
                remoteImage.getName(),
                remoteImage.getContentType(),
                remoteImage.getContent(),
                remoteImage.getCreatedAt(),
                remoteImage.getOwner(),
                remoteImage.getCamera(),
                remoteImage.getLens(),
                remoteImage.getAperture(),
                remoteImage.getFocalLength(),
                remoteImage.getFocalLength(),
                remoteImage.getISO(),
                remoteImage.getDescription(),
                remoteImage.getOwnerId(),
                remoteImage.getCategoryId()
        );
        service.save(image);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        sendError(409, "Image could not be stored. " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

I tested this function with following Test:

```
@Test
public void testImageUpload() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    login(james.getEmail(), "password");
    RemoteImage image = createTestRemoteImage("test", james);
    List<Image> images = r.path("image")
            .header(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, createAuthenticationHeader("kai@ima.at", "password"))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(new GenericType<List<Image>>() {
            });
    assertThat(images.size(), is(0));
    r.path("image").header(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, createAuthenticationHeader("kai@ima.at", "password")).post(image);
    List<Image> images1 = r.path("image")
            .header(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, createAuthenticationHeader("kai@ima.at", "password"))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(new GenericType<List<Image>>() {
            });
    assertThat(images1.size(), is(1));
}

private RemoteImage createTestRemoteImage(String name, Customer customer) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(getClass().getResource("/images/test.jpg").toURI()));
    RemoteImage image = new RemoteImage(name, "image/jpeg", bytes, bytes, new Date(), customer.getEmail(), "Samsung NX300M", "Minolta MD 1.4", "1.4", "50", "2000", "200", "Test Image description", customer.getId(), 1L);
    return image;
}
```

This seems to work fine so far, but in the Front End, in my case AngularJS, where I have a controller for adding an Image.

```
controllers.controller 'ImageAddController', ['$scope','$routeParams','$location','Image', ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Image) -> 
  $scope.image = {name:"",description:""}
  $scope.error = null

  $scope.add =  -> 
    Image.save $scope.image,
      (text,headers,context) ->
        $scope.error = null
        $location.path('/images/')
      (request) -> 
        $scope.error = request.data
]
```

The matching view for that controller is the following

```
<div class="body-content">
    <h1>Add Image</h1>
    <div class="panel col-lg-8 col-offset-2">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">New Image</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" data-ng-bind="error" data-ng-show="error"></div>
        <form novalidate name="imageForm" class="css-form">
            <fieldset>                
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
                           data-ng-model="image.name" required name="name"/>
                </div>     
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description"  
                           data-ng-model="image.description" required name="description"/>
                </div>          
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category" class="control-label">Category</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category"  
                           data-ng-model="image.categoryId" name="category"
                           required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="camera" class="control-label">Camera</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="camera"  
                           data-ng-model="image.camera" name="camera"
                           required />
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lens" class="control-label">Lens</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lens"  
                           data-ng-model="image.lens" name="lens"
                           required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="aperture" class="control-label">Aperture</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="aperture"  
                           data-ng-model="image.aperture" name="aperture"
                           required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="focalLength" class="control-label">Focal length</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="focalLength"  
                           data-ng-model="image.focalLength" name="focalLength"
                           required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shutterSpeed" class="control-label">Shutter speed</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shutterSpeed"  
                           data-ng-model="image.shutterSpeed" name="shutterSpeed"
                           required />
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ISO" class="control-label">ISO</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ISO"  
                           data-ng-model="image.ISO" name="ISO"
                           required />
                </div>

            </fieldset> 
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="add()"
                        data-ng-disabled="customerForm.$invalid">Save</button>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            </div>    
        </form>    
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how do let the user upload a picture to save it in the JSON (byte[] content) and how would I be able to display that image from an JSON for the user?

PS: The controller is not writen in Javascipt, it is Coffeescript. But because I guess more of you understand Javascript, you can help me in that language.

Comment: Use a base64 encoder and encode content to as base64 img and put it in an <img> tag , ie. <img  src="data:image/***type***;base64,*** contentAsBase64 ***" />

Comment: ok, thank you. But how do i let the user upload the image?

Comment: You could use HTML5 File Api. Didn't try it but it will work for your case

Comment: I will try this out for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file