# how to preview an image before uploading and replace it with older image after uploading in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hai i am trying to preview an image before it uploading to server and have to replace it with older image.
here is my html code:::::::

```
 <img class=" thumbnail" data-ng-hide="imageSource==NULL" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" ng-hide="user.pic" ng-src="{{imageSource}}">

            <img class="hai thumbnail img-responsive" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" data-ng-show="!imageSource" ng-src="{{user.pic}}">

            <div >
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                  <span class="fileinput-new upload-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> select image</span>

                <input class="file-upload" ng-model="user.pic" id="FilePhoto"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
                </span>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="upload()">upload me
                </button>
```

my script code looks like this.......

```
$scope.file_changed = function (element) {
            console.log('llllllll');
            var files = element.files; // FileList object
            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
            for (var i = 0, photofile; photofile = files[i]; i++) {

                var photofile = element.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {

                    return function (e) {
$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        $rootScope.imageSource = e.target.result;
                        console.log('lllllllldddddddddddddd' + JSON.stringify($scope.imageSource));
                        $scope.img=true;

                    };
                })(photofile);
                reader.readAsDataURL(photofile);

            };


        }
```

controller for uploading image.............

```
 $scope.upload = function () {

            console.log('imageeeee' + JSON.stringify($rootScope.imageSource));
            var image = {
                pic: $rootScope.imageSource,
            };
            userss.updateimage.update(image, function (result) {
                console.log("sucessfully image uploaded" + JSON.stringify(result));
            });
        }
```

please help me to solve this problem. every thing working good but i cant able to preview image

Comment: I feel like this is more an angular question that javascript/jquery/html. Can you get this to work outside of angular?

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file