# How to pass value of ng-repeat variable into input["file"]'s onchange function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside of an `ng-repeat="item in vm.items` I have the following `input["file"]`:

```
<input type="file" 
       ng-attr-id="image{{item}}"
       class="form-control"
       accept="image/*"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().vm.openFile(event, item)"
       required>
```

I am calling `vm.openFile` using `onchange` instead of `ng-change` because `ng-change` is not supported for `input["file"]` types.

The problem, now, is that I am unable to pass `item` to my `onchange` function because of the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined`

How can I pass the value of `item`, which is just a string, into my `onchange` function within `ng-repeat`?

Comment: It would be nicer to define `ng-model` for your inputs so you can keep everything within angular without needing to use `onchange`.

Comment: It would be nicer, however, ng-model is not supported for `input["file"]`.  Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see that. It seems a bit hacky, but what if you changed `item` in your `onchange` to `{{ item }}`?

Comment: I did try it and it returns a parse error.

Comment: In that case, the best I can do for you is give you a link to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file
which you may have already seen.

Comment: Thank you.  I will play around with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `onchange` is a build-in function, it is not compiled by angular but simply execute global-scope javascript. So, since there is no `item` variable in your global scope (which is fine), it crashes.

For the same reason as you could not simply write `vm`, but had to write `angular.element(this).scope().vm`, you will need to use the same for the item variable. Hence the html:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().vm.openFile(event, angular.element(this).scope().item)"
```

Note that I don'tknow where this `event` variable comes from, so you may need to do the same for it if it is an angular thing.

Now this is a hack agisnt Angular design principles, so it would be better to use a directive as pointed out by **David Williams** comment.

Comment: I was hitting my head to find this answer Thank you.