# Upload file creating directive with AngularJs

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I want to create a my directive for read the input type="file" but I fail in this problem. I write the my code in page html in this way:

```
<body ng-controller="insertController">
    <div>
        <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
```

So I want read the file and show the result in {{message}}. So I created a directive in this way:

```
modulo.directive('fileModel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: 'insert.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.message = attrs.fileModel;
        }
    };
});
```

Moreover I read my controller but it's empty...

```
modulo.controller('insertController', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

How can I fix the problem?Thanks!

Comment: You use one of the solutions from this thread. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file