# AngularJS: Get path to file from input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, file-upload, angularjs-directive

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063046/2423123) I'm able to retrieve files from the `input` tag in  base64 encoding via a directive:

```
.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

The `readAsDataURL` will read the file as base64.

How is it possible to get the **path** to the selected file from the `input` tag? e.g. `file:///....`

Comment: file inputs do not give the path for security reasons...

Comment: That is too bad in my case...