# Issues with Binding ng-model with calculated field in the html DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Form elements

```
<input  ng-model="student.person.firstName" type="text"/>
    <textarea ng-model="student.person.photo" id="imageText" >
    </textarea>
<input type="file" ng-model="" id="imageUpload" onchange="getbase64();"/>
```

`base64()` method sets the text for `<textarea>`.
Now JS code

```
$scope.saveInfo = function(){    
    console.log($scope.student.person.firstName);
    console.log($scope.student.person.photo);
};
```

I don't get anything in person.photo whereas `person.firstName` gets me the value of the name.
Is there a binding problem because i'm setting the value of the `<textarea>` using js with base64 content

http://plnkr.co/edit/cElm8PD3hNzEWBNesegW?p=catalogue plunker link.

Comment: Show the code on a plunker or something

Comment: where you call `$scope.saveInfo`? can you provide also `getbase64()`?

Comment: Is getbase64 called? Please provide some sample code...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cElm8PD3hNzEWBNesegW?p=catalogue    yes the getbase64() method does get called. And also I can see the base64 converted string in the text area.

Comment: @Pavan, are you know that you mix angular code and none angular?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-model for <input type="file"/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually trigger the change event (inside fileReader.onload ), something like:

```
 var element = document.getElementById('imageText');
 if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
 } else
    element.fireEvent("onchange");
```

working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QGCl6ly5HMmAoDwyt4YO?

Comment: here element is something we want to have change event fired for??

Comment: Can you please explain a little why it did not work my way. And what did your code do?

Comment: @Pavan this _ABOS_ answer :-) anyway your way not work because angular don't know that something change