# Errors in validation to validate file extension before uploading the file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, valdr

I tried this custom validator to validate file extension of selected file.

I use **valdr-validation-plugin** with AngularJS and have written this custom validation to validate the extension of the file which is to be uploaded.
Generally `value` parameter contains the details of the data which is to be validated, but in case of file upload its not working.

```js
app.factory('fileValidator', function () {
return {
    name: 'fileExtension',
    validate: function (value, arguments)
    {

            if(value=== undefined) { return false; }
            else
            {
                var fileName = value.name,
                    extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                if( extension == "jpg" || extension == "jpeg" || extension == "png" || extension == "bmp" ){ return true; }
                else { return false; }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

In above code, I try to get the extension of file using `value` parameter but it showing error that **value is undefined**.

I call this custom validation from the below code. Register that validator to the app config and then used it to validate bannerImage.

```js
app.config(function(valdrProvider) {
    valdrProvider.addValidator('fileValidator');
    valdrProvider.addConstraints({
        "Banner":
        {
            "bannerName":
            {
                "size":
                {
                    "min": 2,
                    "max": 512,
                    "message": "Banner name must between 2 and 512 characters"
                },
                "required" :
                {
                    "message" : "This field is required"
                }
            },
            "bannerLink":
            {
                "size":
                {
                    "min": 2,
                    "max": 1024,
                    "message": "Banner link must between 2 and 1024 characters"
                },
                "required" :
                {
                    "message" : "This field is required"
                }
            },
            "bannerImage":
            {
                "fileExtension":
                {
                    "allowedExtensions" : ['jpg','jpeg', 'png','bmp'],
                    "message" : "Allowed file types are JPG, JPEG, PNG, BMP"
                },
                "required":
                {
                    "required" : "This field is required"
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Its not working and shows lot of errors. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Take a look at some workarounds to getting the value from a `<input type="file">` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Comment: I have made a few grammar corrections in the content, removed the wrong indentation for text within the code blocks to make them visible. I have also removed the thanks note as it is not required and  the framework, add-on names from the title as they are also not required due to presence of tags.

Comment: You could could do everybody who wants to help a real favor if you created an example at Plunkr e.g. fork this http://plnkr.co/edit/5J66D2EFCuhhTOYantUm and adjust accordingly.