# How to get values of input type file in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, slim

I am creating simple application in angularjs using slim framework. In that, I am creating form for some data like name, categories, currency and Image file etc. In this app, I am having trouble with input type file. I can get all the data of textbox or radio button etc but I can't get data of input type file. Below is the code for that.
**index.html** :- HTML file

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form account-form" name="form" ng-submit="creator(user)" role="form">
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name"  /> 

<input type="radio" name="category" ng-model="user.category" value="Science" >                                  
<input type="radio" name="category" ng-model="user.category" value="Engineerig" >

<input type="file" ng-model="user.image_file" name="image_file">
</form>
```

**registerController.js** :- Controller file

```
app.controller('CreatorController', function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$http,CreatorService,FlashService) {
    $scope.creator = function (user) {
      // alert("create");
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
         CreatorService.creator(user)
                .then(function (response) {   
                    if(response.data['message']){ 
                        FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                        $location.path('/crete-page');
                    } else {
                        FlashService.Error('Registration failed');
                    }
                });
    }    
});
```

**registerDB.php** :- DB handler PHP file in slim framework dir

```
 <?php

function insertUser($data) {

    print_r($data); //Getting All data here from form but not getting File values
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-model for <input type="file"/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it to a server you can't just receive the file and send it, sometimes you have to transform it in a blob or something.

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/)

```
don't know if it works but you can try. (stupid stackoverflow makes me put code after a fiddle link, wtf!)
```

Or else you can use [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload), at least was what I used when I tried to do something like that. But I was using nodejs on the server and even on server I had to receive using another library specific for the situation. Dunno how it works with php.

GL!

Answer (score 0):

This may be old question but i came across same problem and this is how i fixed it.

add this code to **registerController.js**

```
function getPath() {
        $('#filePath ').on('change',function ()
        {
            var filePath = $(this).val();
            $scope.fileURL = filePath;
        });
    }
getPath();
```

**$scope.fileURL** will then hold the data/value for the input file. you can then set **user.image_file** to be this value "$scope.fileURL"
and your **html** should be

```
<input id="filePath " type="file" ng-model="user.image_file" name="image_file">
```

hope this helps