# How to validate image File using Angular-js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

am using angular-js for image file validation. i want to find out "is it image File or not"..here am compare the extension of file to identify the file is correct or not..

but my code is not work!..it doesn't show any error. am literally confused

anyone have the answers command here!..

Thanks in advance!

my  Code is

---

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Validate image on upload</TITLE>
  <script src = "angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
<center>
<div ng-app="prabhu"  ng-controller="mycontroller">


    Upload an image: <INPUT type="file" name="image_file" ng-model="fil.name">  
    //<h1>the file is {{val.validate())}}</h1>
 <p ng-bind="val.validate()"> <p>
 </div>
</center>
<script >

 var myapp = angular.module("prabhu",[]);
 myapp.controller("mycontroller",function($scope){

    $scope.val={            
        ref = ['jpg','jpeg','png'],         
        validate:function(){

            name = fil.name | lowercase;
            length = name.length();
            ext = name.LastIndexOf(".")+1;          
            ext1 = name.substring(ext,length);          
            //k = 0;            
            for (k=0 ; k <= 4;k++){
                if(ref[k]==ext1){
                    return "valid File Format";

                }
                //else
                //  return "invalid File Format";
            }           
            return "invalid File Format";
        }
    }; 
 });
 </script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

---

Comment: Is requirement to restrict file type to image ?

Comment: just in case did you perhaps forget the `n` in the directive `ng-model="fil.name"`? Also just to be safe, you should declare $scope.fil = {"name":null}

Comment: You may want to also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Comment: my requirement is to select image files only!.

Comment: i am correct 'n' in directive. thanks

Comment: "name" is a reference variable (extensions) used to compare with "File extension"

Answer (score 5):

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/75scqotk/3/)

As far as I know, no binding support for File Upload control.

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="file" ng-model="image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this.files)" />
```

**In controller:**

```
$scope.uploadImage = function (files) {           
       var ext = files[0].name.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
       if(angular.lowercase(ext) ==='jpg' || angular.lowercase(ext) ==='jpeg' || angular.lowercase(ext) ==='png'){
        alert("Valid File Format");
       }  
       else{
        alert("Invalid File Format");
       }       
    }
```

Comment: Test with a `.png` image to see the output.

Comment: I have updated my answer and fiddle, please check it again.

Comment: If any answer solve your problem, you should mark that answer as accepted. [For detail, visit this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> my requirement is to select image files only!.

Try using `accept` attribute at `input type="file"` element

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```