# AngularJS ng model for input type image

Tags: angularjs, image, input, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

Is it possible to bind ng-model for input type image, something like this:

```
<input ng-model="imageName" type="image" ng-src="{{imageSrc}}">
```

I didn't find info in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), so I have tried, but without success.

Comment: This has already been asked before. See the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can create.

I have created a fiddle for [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ofwvhn6/1/), Hope it will resolve your problem

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="test">
      <input ng-model="imageName" type="image" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
   </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function test($scope){
  $scope.imageName = 'logo';
  $scope.imageUrl='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
}
```

Comment: $scope.imageName is still undefined :(