# How to create and save file to local fileSystem using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file

I want to create and save file before I log data into it. The method below is creating and saving data to file and it is only supported by Chrome browser. How can I create and save blank file and then log data into it and has IE and Chrome support?

ctrl.js:

```
function download(text, name, type) {
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = name;
}
$scope.recordLogs = function(){
    download('file text', 'myfilename.txt', 'text/plain')
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**Save to filesystem**

Have a look at [angular-file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver)

Or use the following code as a reference in saving a BLOB. Where the `blob` object is generated from a `JSON` Object. But extration to a `TEXT` file is also possible.

```
    // export page definition to json file
    $scope.exportToFile = function(){
        var filename = 'filename'       
        var blob = new Blob([angular.toJson(object, true)], {type: 'text/plain'});
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
        } else{
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = filename;
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
            e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
            // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href); // clean the url.createObjectURL resource
        }
    }
```

**Using LocalStorage**

Saving to localStorage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

Getting from localStorage

```
window.localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Delete key from localStorage

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Or using the AngularJS module ['ngStorage'](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

**Browser compatibility**

```
Chrome - 4    
Firefox (Gecko) - 3.5    
Internet Explorer - 8    
Opera - 10.50    
Safari (WebKit) - 4
```

**See live example (credits to @cOlz)**

https://codepen.io/gMohrin/pen/YZqgQW

Comment: I am not quite sure how it will work with above code in question, i want to create file without the data and once file is created then i will push data into it, Also when we create a file , does user has choice to set the filename and location ?

Comment: See the updated code sample. Which illustrated how to save a BLOB (Binary Large OBject) to a file - setting the filename yourself.

Comment: file is being downloaded its not giving option to user to set the file name once download complete it throws error  `TypeError: Failed to execute 'revokeObjectURL' on 'URL': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
    at TypeError (native)`

Comment: The file is downloaded automatically according the given filename. Call the 'revokeObjectURL' to clean up the objectURL resource, be sure to include the url in the method.

Comment: I made a codepen from this answer:
https://codepen.io/gMohrin/pen/YZqgQW

Comment: The commented out line of code should be `window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);`.

Answer (score 9):

```
$http({

            method : 'GET',
            url : $scope.BASEURL + 'file-download?fileType='+$scope.selectedFile,
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }

        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // TODO when WS success
            var file = new Blob([ data ], {
                type : 'application/json'
            });
            //trick to download store a file having its URL
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var a         = document.createElement('a');
            a.href        = fileURL; 
            a.target      = '_blank';
            a.download    = $scope.selectedFile+'.json';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
```

In success part need to open local system, by which the user can choose, where to save file. Here I have used `<a>`. And I am hitting restful service

Answer (score 1):

### How to Download Files Locally with AngularJS (with DEMO)

Use an `<a>` tag with a `download` attribute:

```
<a download="{{files[0].name}}" xd-href="data">
  <button>Download data</button>
</a>
```

The `xd-href` Directive:

```
app.directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
     });
  };
});
```

When downloading, browsers prompt user with a dialog that can be accepted or cancelled. For more information, see [MDN HTML Reference - `<a>` Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

## [THE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/giPFMG3xSLW7GO9Eorqb?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myVm", function($scope, $http, $window) {
  var vm = $scope;
  var url = "//httpbin.org/post";
  var config = { headers: {"Content-Type": undefined} };

  vm.upload = function() {
    vm.spin = "Uploading...";
    $http.post(url, vm.files[0], config).
     then(function(response) {
      vm.result = "SUCCESS";
      vm.data = response.data.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
      vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
    }).finally(function() {
      vm.spin = undefined
    });
  };
})
.directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
     });
  };
})
.directive("selectNgFiles", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myVm">
    <h2>Upload and Download File with AngularJS</h2>
    <input type="file" select-ng-files ng-model="files">
    <br>
    <code>
    Name: {{files[0].name}}<br>
    Size: {{files[0].size}}<br>
    Type: {{files[0].type}}<br>
    Date: {{files[0].lastModifiedDate}}<br>
    </code>
    <button ng-click="upload()" ng-disabled="!files">
      Upload
    </button>
    <span ng-show="spin">{{spin}}</span>
    <span ng-show="result">{{result}}</span>
    <a download="data_{{files[0].name}}" xd-href="data">
      <button ng-disabled="!data">Download data</button>
    </a>
    
  </body>
```

See also [ng-model for `<input type=“file”/>` (with directive DEMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245)