# WebApi download response as file

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, content-negotiation

I have an issue with my WebApi. Based on the request, the response is returned either as `json` or `csv`. For serialization I use `NewtonSoft.Json` and my own `CsvMediaTypeFormatter`. As long as I test it from Postman, the response works as expected.

What I struggle with it that I'd like to force the browser to save the file in case the response is `csv`. To achieve that, in my `CsvMediaTypeFormatter` I overrode the `SetDefaultContentHeaders` method as follows:

```
public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
{
    base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);

    headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                                 {
                                     FileName = "content.csv"
                                 };
}
```

When I test my API using Postman, I see the csv content as the body, also the headers show `content-disposition: attachment; filename=content.csv`.

But when it's hit from the browser (I tried Firefox, Chrome and Edge), there's no "Save file as..." dialog. However, the dev tools show the call being made and the response having the `content-disposition` header value.

I tried with various `Content-type` values: `text/csv`, `text/plain`, `application/octet-stream` or `application/x-unknown`, but no success.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you use some js framework for making the http call, you might need to manually dump the content to a file. Below are examples for AngularJS and Angular2.

AngularJS:

```
this.$http(req).success(data => {
    const file = new Blob([data],
        {
            type: "text/csv"
        });

    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.download = `yourfilename.csv`;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
});
```

Angular2+

```
downloadFile(data: Response){
    const file = new Blob([data],
        {
            type: "text/csv"
        });
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

[How to create and save file to local fileSystem using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462894/how-to-create-and-save-file-to-local-filesystem-using-angularjs)

[How do I download a file with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2/35210392)