# How to add Angular service response into JSON file

Tags: angular

I'm dealing with a huge dataSet using Angular5 service, so I want to call the backend API once and want to save the result into JSON.

I fetch the response and then store into several arrays according to my need,I'm looking how to add those arrays into JSON file.

```
getAllConcepts(){
   let allOrderUUID="b3dac224-fdea-11e4-b248-005056820298";
 this.allOrderableService.getAllOrderableConcepts(allOrderUUID).subscribe(allOrders=>{
    let allOrderable=allOrders;
    allOrderable.setMembers[0].setMembers.forEach(labSample=>{
      this.labSamples.push(labSample);
    });
    allOrderable.setMembers[1].setMembers.forEach(radOrder=>{
      this.radiologyOrder.push(radOrder);
    });
    this.separatePanelAndLabTestInlabSamples(this.labSamples);
    this.separatePanelAndOrderInRadiologyLab(this.radiologyOrder);    
  });
}

separatePanelAndLabTestInlabSamples(labSample:any){
  console.log("@receivedLabSample",labSample);
  if(labSample.length>0)
  {
    labSample[0].setMembers.forEach(response=>{
      if(response.conceptClass.uuid==="33a6291c-8a92-11e4-977f-0800271c1b75")
        {
          this.labSamplesTest.push(response);
        }
     if(response.conceptClass.uuid==="8d492026-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f")
        {
          this.labSamplesPanel.push(response);
        }
  });
  console.log("LabTest",this.labSamplesTest);
  console.log("LabPanel",this.labSamplesPanel);
  }
}
```

I'm able to receive the response,after getting the reponse I'm storing them into severals arrays,I'm confuse how I can add these array into JSON file for future use.The basic aim is to reduce the call to server.

I want to add following arrays that exist in code into JSON File.

I have all the arrays, I need to convert them into JSON file.

Comment: That is not a client side dedicated functionality, even you can achieve it by workarounds, but still not recommended to write in files on the client side, else, If it is a `HUGE` response , why you do not just implement pagination in your server side ?

Comment: this is just a utility which require once,Once I stored the result into json,I will deal with it.Are you sure it's not possible in angular?

Comment: I did not say it is not possible, you can achieve it in JS, but it is not recommended for security reasons. `Localstorage` wont help ?

Comment: Will you please share a way,how I can acheive it in JS,security is not big concern for me.

Comment: And you'll continue using that file during application runtime or you just want response data to be stored in a file that'll be downloaded and that's all ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and save file to local fileSystem using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462894/how-to-create-and-save-file-to-local-filesystem-using-angularjs)

Comment: I want to store it once,after that I want to use it during application where needed.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't save response to a file in angular, for that you need server-side access.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into PouchDB. It's a javascript version of CouchDB. It's noSQL based (with documents). So you could do then is to fetch the data, store them into the (local) pouchDB instance. Then from that point on, you just do calls to pouchdb.