# Angular js change 'file' type to 'text' type [Safari]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

I have inputs that build from objects in array.

Everything got right but when `input.type = 'file'`, Angular change it to **text type** and i cant figure it out.

Did anything notice this?

**My template:**

```
<span ng-repeat="input in formInputs">
    <label for="{{input.id}}">{{input.label}}</label>
    <input type="{{input.type}}" id="{{input.id}}" name="{{input.name}}" ng-model="input.insert" ng-required="input.must">
</span>
```

**My array:**

```
var formInputs = [
    {
        label     : 'first name',
        id        : 'id1',
        type      : 'text',
        name      : 'name1',
        must      : true,
        insert    : ''
    },
    {
        label     : 'upload file',
        id        : 'id2',
        type      : 'file',
        name      : 'name2',
        must      : true,
        insert    : ''
    }
]
```

**My result:**

```
<span ng-repeat="input in formInputs">
  <label for="id1">first name</label>
  <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" ng-model="input.insert" ng-required="input.must">
  <label for="id2">upload file</label>
  <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" ng-model="input.insert" ng-required="input.must">
</span>
```

**EDIT:**

I have this flowing:

```
<input type="{{childInput.type}}" id="{{childInput.id}}" name="{{childInput.name}}">
```

And this array:

```
var formInputs = [
    {
        id        : 'id',
        type      : 'file',
        name      : 'name',
    }
]
```

The resolute [only in Safari]:

```
<input type="text" id="id" name="name">
```

Why its happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-model for <input type="file"/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)

Comment: Looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10860/

Comment: Its don't looks good, whats is your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AngularJS Documentation for input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input):

> **Note**: Not every feature offered is available for all input types. Specifically, data binding and event handling via `ng-model` is unsupported for `input[file]`.

So it looks like Angular falls back to `type="text"`. There are a lot of answers which bring solutions to this, check out:

- [ng-model for `<input type=“file”/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)

From that answer, here's a way to deal with a file input.

> ```
> .directive("fileread", [function () {
>     return {
>         scope: {
>             fileread: "="
>         },
>         link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
>             element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
>                 var reader = new FileReader();
>                 reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
>                     scope.$apply(function () {
>                         scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
>                     });
>                 }
>                 reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
>             });
>         }
>     }
> }]);
> ```

As mentionned by [Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095132/angular-js-change-file-type-to-text-type/40095281#comment67463281_40095132), his [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10860/) seem to work (with Angular 1.0.1) at first sight, but it doesn't seem to populate the model correctly.

Comment: I have a dynamic types in my objects, and all i need it my objects type insert into the input type in my template. Why its change "file" string to "text"? Sorry but i didn't get it.

Comment: @ZeevKatz Because `ng-model` doesn't support the file input, it looks like it falls back to a text input.

Comment: ok, i remove ng-model from my input and its don't work. I'm edit my question.

Comment: its happen in safari only!

Comment: @ZeevKatz You can't use `ng-model` with `type="file"`, even if it don't fallback to type text, the file input is a special case.

Comment: I'm understand what you saying but i have another problem, safari change file type to text type from file type (without ng-model). File type showing only if i write it manually, and if i take it from the type value in my object its change to text type (only with angular and safari). You know this problem?

Comment: @ZeevKatz Oh sorry for the misunderstanding, I've just seen the edit in your question. I do not have Safari, so testing this will be hard and I won't be able to easily help further.

Comment: @ZeevKatz You could test if the problem arises with vanilla JS (or with jQuery) and if it's the case, ask a new question specific to the file input type being dynamically set while using Safari