# Upload multiple File Using angularjs with custom data for each one?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have class like this

```
 public class UnitDocuments
    {
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        public int DocType { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase UpFile { get; set; }
     }
```

I try to build my own function to send data from html page to mvc controller using angular js

the angular js model looks like this

```
{"UnitId":0,"DocType":1,"UpFile":{}}]
```

and using angularjs directive i can fill the UpFile with uploaded data like the post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063046/4184713)
and the model changed

```
[{"UnitId":0,"DocType":1,"UpFile":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADQAAAAlCAYAAAAN8sr"},[{"UnitId":0,"DocType":5,"UpFile":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADQAAAAlCAYAAAAN8sr"}]]
```

when send this to MVC Controller always get null value for UpFile

```
   public ActionResult Create(List<UnitDocuments> unitDocuments)
{
}
```

is there any way to do something like this ? i expect for each item in unitDocuments list there is a file with its related data

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a directive and a `FileReader` in order to transform the selected file to a data url format as this will make it harder to send to the server. You could directly use `FormData`. For example let's suppose that you have in your view an HTML `<form>` element that represents the data in your view model:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/someresource/create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="[0].UnitId" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].DocType" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="[0].UpFile" />

    <input type="text" name="[1].UnitId" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].DocType" value="2" />
    <input type="file" name="[1].UpFile" />

    <input type="text" name="[2].UnitId" value="5" />
    <input type="text" name="[2].DocType" value="8" />
    <input type="file" name="[2].UpFile" />

    ...
</form>
```

Here's how you can send this information to the server using an AJAX request:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var fd = new FormData(myForm);
$http.post(myForm.action, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
})
.success(function() {
})
.error(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

LAYOUT PAGE

```
<html ng-app="myFormApp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/Demo/angular.js"></script>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<style>
    .layout-header {
        background-color: #0090c3;
        height: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="layout-header">    
</div>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
return {
    scope: true,        //create a new scope
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.bind('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                //emit event upward
                scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
            }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

INDEX.CSHTML

```
<div ng-controller="CTRL_Demo">
<input type="hidden" ng-model="CTRL_Demo.Id"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="CTRL_Demo.FirstName" />
<input type="text" ng-model="CTRL_Demo.LastName"/>
<input type="file" name="file" file-upload />
<button ng-click="SaveEmployee()" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

ANGULAR CONTROLLER CODE

```
    var app = angular.module('myFormApp', []);
    app.controller('CTRL_Demo', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.CTRL_Demo = {};
    $scope.CTRL_Demo.Id = 101;
    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.files.push(args.file);
        });
    });

    $scope.GetUserList = function () {
        $http.get("/User/GetEmployee")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }
    $scope.GetUserList();

    $scope.SaveEmployee = function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Id", $scope.CTRL_Demo.Id);
        formData.append("FirstName", $scope.CTRL_Demo.FirstName);
        formData.append("LastName", $scope.CTRL_Demo.LastName);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("file" + i, $scope.files[i]);
        }   
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/User/SaveEmployee",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success!");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("failed!");
        });
    }

    $scope.uploadFile = function (files) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", files[0]);

        $http.post('@Url', fd, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).success(function () {

        }).error(function () {

        });
    };
});
```

MVC CONTROLLER CODE

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveEmployee(UserViewModel model)
{
    string _fileName = "";
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
         var _empid = int.Parse(Request.Form["Id"]);
         var _file = Request.Files[0];
         var _fName = Request.Files["file0"].FileName;
         var _dotIndex = _fName.LastIndexOf('.');
         var _ext = _fName.Substring(_dotIndex);
         var _configpath = RequestHelpers.GetConfigurationValue("ImageUpload");
         _fileName = _empid + "_IDPROOF" + _ext;
         var _dirPath = Server.MapPath(_configpath);
         var _filePath = Server.MapPath(_configpath) + _fileName;
         if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(_dirPath))
         {
              if (System.IO.File.Exists(_filePath))
              {
                   System.IO.File.Delete(_filePath);
              }
              _file.SaveAs(_filePath);
         }
         else
         {
              System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(_dirPath);
              _file.SaveAs(_filePath);
         }
     }
     return Json(_IUser_Repository.GetUser(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```