# Handling file submit API response in angular

Tags: angularjs, json, forms

I have a **form** where a user uploads a file to my node server, does some stuff, and sends a JSON response.

I do not make the POST through the control, its via submitting a form. After my node code does some stuff, it sends this response succesfully.

```
                  res.json({ 
                    results: "TRUE",
                    file: rows,
                    column: pIndex,
                    rowCount: rows.length 
                  })
```

**Problem, i need to access this json response in my angular app.** After a user submits form, they see raw json of this response and the app redirects to my endpoint: `http://localhost:8000/upload-file`

What do i do to access this response in my angular app without uploading file via controller($http.post)

I have no idea, im much new to javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you aren't using the Angular controller. A regular HTML form, by default will attempt to make a URL params encoded POST request to the URL defined in the `action=""` attribute, or, if not defined, it will POST to the current URL. The result of the post is then simply spit out into the browser window.

Angular has a directive `ngSubmit` that is for intercepting this default behavior so that you can handle it in a controller:

```
<form ng-submit="mySubmitHandler()">
...
  <input type="text" ng-model="formData.myField"/>
</form>
```

In your Angular controller you can now do whatever you wish. Typically you make a POST request using the `$http` provider:

```
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {
    myField: '',
  };
  $scope.mySubmitHandler = function () {
    $http.post('/someUrl', formData).then(function(response) {
      //handle the response from Node.js
    });
  };
}
```

The problem with this is that you are trying to upload a file. Trying to upload files with `$http` can be daunting. Your best bet is to use a 3rd party library to facilitate file upload in angular, such as [`ng-file-upload`](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). It will come with it's own set of instructions that will allow you to handle the Node response inside of Angular.

Comment: thanks, but i tried using just the html form to avoid worrying about file to cntrl etc. 

how do i bind a file to $scope.formData ?

Comment: Here's some more info about Angular and the file input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file. However, your may struggle to make this work

Answer (score 1):

### Upload File with AngularJS

**The template**

```
<input type=file files-input ng-model="files" /><br>
<button ng-disabled="!files[0]" ng-click="upload()">Upload</button><br>
```

The <kbd>Upload</kbd> button becomes active after the file is selected.

**The `files-input` Directive**

```
app.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
         elem.on("change", function (e) {
             ngModel.$setViewValue(elem[0].files);
         });
      }
  };
});
```

The directive uses the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) to bind the selected files to a scope variable.

**The `upload()` function**

```
var vm = $scope;
var url = "API URL";
var config = { headers: {"Content-Type": undefined} };

vm.upload = function() {

    //USE formData for Content-Type multipart/formdata        
    //var formData = new $window.FormData();
    //formData.append("file-0", vm.files[0]);

    //USE files[0] for binary upload
    $http.post(url, vm.files[0], config)
     .then(function(response) {
        vm.result = "SUCCESS";
        vm.data = response.data.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
        vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
    });
};
```

It is important to set `Content-Type: undefined` so that the AngularJS framework doesn't set the content type to `application/json`. The [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) will then set the content type according the type of the given object.

It is more efficient to send the file directly, but if content type `multipart/formdata` with [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is desired, use the [formData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to create a `formData` object for the XHR API to send.

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/QrsDL60NP4n6ZgLAzH8p?p=preview)