# Angular upload csv file into scope not post to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I am trying to allow users to upload a CSV file so that the values can then be displayed and validated. I do not want to upload the file directly to the server, I would like to have it just in scope until it has been validated.

Angular 1.5.8 is unable to bind input types of file to the model [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)
 so I'm looking at using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/) but all options seem to require uploading to the server. I am unable to find a library that will help me get an input type file into scope.

So my question is: how can I get a csv file into angular scope?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, sorry I can't give you votes I don't have enough reputation. I used your file reader code inside my directive's link function. `link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    uploadFile = (event) ->
    <your file reader code>
    element.bind('change', uploadFile)`

Comment: But I think you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark under the vote count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FileReader for files that have been selected by the user(!)

Your file input:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
```

Listening for a change event on the element:

```
document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   if(!file)
      return;

   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contents = e.target.result;
      // add it to a $scope variable
      $scope.fileContent = contents;
      $scope.$apply();    // if you are outside of the AngularJS digest cycle
   };
   reader.readAsText(file);       
}, false);
```