# why $scope.logo is undefined in controller ?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

This is my HTML form

```
<form ng-submit='create()'>
    ..
    .
    .
    <input type='file' ng-model='logo' accept="image/*">
</form>
```

this is my controller :

```
$scope.create = function () {
        $scope.Ent = {}
        $scope.Ent.logo = $scope.logo;
```

[image: This is my console only input file is undefined and all other fileds are alright]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-model for <input type="file"/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` won't work in input type 'file. use a custom directive to bind it

```
.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

assign scope variable to `fileread` attribute

```
<form ng-submit='create()'>
    ..
    .
    .
    <input type='file' fileread='logo' accept="image/*">
</form>
```

Comment: If you find an article in SO which already explains the issue, maybe instead of copying and paste exactly the same code, it would be better to mark the question as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

p.s. or at least refer to that article in the answer