# Remove file from input type file from onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input type="file" in a web page. On onchange event i attached an event from an angular scope to validate the selected file.
This is my input element:

```
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().validateFile(this)"
 accept="application/pdf, application/x-pdf, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, 
 image/gif, image/png, image/bmp, image/x-windows-bmp, image/tiff, image/x-tiff"/>
```

This is my validate method and it doesn't work to remove the element with `e.preventDefault()` or with `return false`:

```
 $scope.validateFile = function (e) {
        var result = dmsTaskSevice.validateFile(e)

        if (result.isValid === false){
            alert(result.message);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

There is any way to remove the file just selected?

Comment: Does `e.value = undefined` not work?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `e.value = ""`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist

Comment: @NiK648: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: `element.scope()` will not work in case you will use [recommended production settings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) like `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)`. It is much better to use [custom directive for the `input type="file"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44973187/4222181).