# AngularJS: one upload button that uploads three images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

**Introduction**

At the moment I have three upload buttons that upload three different images using three different functions.

Is there a way to have one button that each time you click it, it uploads a new image?

**Question**

As each upload has a different function, I was thinking hide the button once the image is uploaded. So hide button 2 and 3 and use button one to upload, print out saying image name but hides 1st button and shows second. Repeat this process until all buttons are used (if user uses all).

**Update**

the 3 images have to upload to there own function.

*First* image to `insertImageFirst`

*Second* to `insertImageSecond`

*Third* to `insertImageThird`

**My code**

```
<div class="controls row center-text">
        <input type="file" id="FirstImageID" name="image" class="" accept="image/*"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().insertImageFirst()"/>

        <input type="file" id="SecondImageID" name="image" class="" accept="image/*"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().insertImageSecond()"/>

        <input type="file" id="ThirdImageID" name="image" class="" accept="image/*"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().insertImageThird()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to just upload them all at once?

Comment: @PatrickEvans if each Image could upload to each function as in 1 2 and 3.

Comment: I got it. Can you please show us `insertImageFirst()` function?

Comment: @KarolTrybulec upload three images three different functions `insertImageThird` `insertImageSecond` `insertImageFirst`

Comment: So if a user can upload 200 images, you will have 200 times the same function, all the way like `insertImageOneHundredAndThirtySeventh` ?Do you believe this is a smart code design?

Comment: @JeremyThille no its not smart, that is why I am asking for advice. a user should only be able to upload 3 images.

Comment: Hmmm... Just out of curiosity, why do inputs have IDs? `id="FirstImageID"` ?

Comment: IMO you can just do `onchange="insertImage(1)"`,  `onchange="insertImage(2)"` and test the passed argument from inside your single function. `function insertImage(num){ if(num==1)..... }`

Comment: Consider using a custom directive that enables `<input type=file>` to automatically work with the `ng-change` directive. See [ng-model for `<input type=“file”/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245).

Comment: @JeremyThille thats a brilliant idea, thanks.

Comment: @georgeawg nice, i was thinking along the lines of ng if or change. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple solution that also limits the user to only three images.

However I know its messy and also hides the labels of the image that uploaded.

can anyone improve this to show how to display the labels or how to do this without multiple uploads.

**My Code**

```
<div class="controls row center-text">
    <input type="file" id="FirstImageID" name="image" class="" accept="image/*"
           onchange="angular.element(this).scope().insertImageFirst()"
           ng-click=" showDiv1=true"
           ng-show="!showDiv1"/>


    <div ng-show="showDiv1">
        <input type="file" id="SecondImageID" name="image" class="" accept="image/*"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().insertImageSecond()"
               ng-click=" showDiv2=true"
               ng-show="!showDiv2"/>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="showDiv2">
    <input type="file" id="ThirdImageID" name="image" class="" accept="image/*"
           onchange="angular.element(this).scope().insertImageThird()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a custom directive that enables `<input type=file>` to automatically work with the `ng-change` directive.

```
<input type="file" id="FirstImageID" name="image1" class="" accept="image/*"
       files-input ng-model="fileList1" ng-change="insertImage(1,fileList1[0])"
       ng-disabled="disabledList[1]" />

<input type="file" id="SecondImageID" name="image2" class="" accept="image/*"
       files-input ng-model="fileList2" ng-change="insertImage(2,fileList2[0])"
       ng-disabled="disabledList[2]" />

<input type="file" id="ThirdImageID" name="image3" class="" accept="image/*"
       files-input ng-model="fileList3" ng-change="insertImage(3,fileList3[0])" 
       ng-disabled="disabledList[3]" />
```

```
app.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.disabledList = [];
  vm.insertImage = function(num,file) {
    vm.disabledList[num]=true;
  }
});
```

With the `ng-change` directive, one can use the power of AngularJS expressions to operate an `ng-disabled` directive after each selection.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PQnR2f2m8HjWOZm8A2JM?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
})
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.completedList = [];
  vm.disabledList = [];
  vm.insertImage = function(num,file) {
    vm.completedList.unshift("num="+num+" file="+file.name);
    vm.disabledList[num]=true;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="file" id="FirstImageID" name="image1" class="" accept="image/*"
   files-input ng-model="fileList1" ng-change="insertImage(1,fileList1[0])"
   ng-disabled="disabledList[1]" />
<br>
<input type="file" id="SecondImageID" name="image2" class="" accept="image/*"
   files-input ng-model="fileList2" ng-change="insertImage(2,fileList2[0])"
   ng-disabled="disabledList[2]" />
<br>
<input type="file" id="ThirdImageID" name="image3" class="" accept="image/*"
   files-input ng-model="fileList3" ng-change="insertImage(3,fileList3[0])" 
   ng-disabled="disabledList[3]" />
<br>
<div ng-repeat="item in completedList track by $index">
  {{item}}
</div>
</body>
```