# using angular.js to submit <input type=“file”/>,how to convert text/plain to multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my question is different from [File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)
I have got the data of file. But when request, the content-type is text/plain, but I need multipart/form-data. So how can I convert? What is wrong with the code?
[here is what console showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiuRy.png)

html:

```
<form ng-submit="processForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label"><span class="tip" ng-hide="data.id">*</span>ID：</label>
        <input class="input" name="id" ng-model="data.id" maxlength="5">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="preview" fileread="data.preview">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-small">save</button>
</form>
```

js: [ng-model for <input type="file"/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file)

```
.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

when click to commit:

```
$scope.processForm = function(){
    var data = $scope.data,
        url = Api.add,
        config;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
     }).then(function(result){
```

Comment: use form data: var formData = new FormData();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Comment: I need multipart/form-data to response. how to convert?