# How to preview .ai , .pdf format images before upload and convert into base64 in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, base64, image-resizing

I use this directive on input type="file" filread="uploadme.src", Now the challenging part is to first convert .ai/.pdf file to .jpg/.png/.gif and resize them and save the base64 text in API. I need solution to convert them first them resize using base64 Uri function as shown in code below.

```
app.directive("fileread", [function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "=",
            fileName: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
                var file, name, reader, size, type;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
                    scope.fileName = {};
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = (loadEvent.target.result);
                        img.onload = function() {
                            var size = calculateAspectRatioFit(this.width, this.height, 100, 100);
                            scope.fileName.size = "_" + size.width + "X" + size.height;
                            //Get resized image
                            scope.fileread = imageToDataUri(this, size.width, size.height);

                        }
                        scope.fileName.src = (loadEvent.target.result);
                        if (angular.isString(name)) {
                            return scope.fileName.name = name;
                        }
                    });
                }

                file = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                name = file.name;
                type = file.type;
                size = file.size;
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```
//Resize the image (in the example 640 x 480px)
function imageToDataUri(img, width, height) {

    // create an off-screen canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // set its dimension to target size
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    // encode image to data-uri with base64 version of compressed image
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {

    var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);

    return {
        width: srcWidth * ratio,
        height: srcHeight * ratio
    };
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @georgeawg : i understand that we have an option to upload the file using an API. But due to project requirement we have only text field in DB to save the image. So we are left with base64 option.

Comment: Why are you doing all of that processing in a directive? It would be wiser to return the file to the controller and process it there.

Comment: @georgeawg : can you demostrate your idea of doing the same in controller for.ai files or .pdf files ?

Comment: See [Working Demo of Directive that Works with ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245) and use the `ng-change` directive to invoke processing in the controller.