# How can I resolve TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).selectFileForUpload is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to upload a file in asp.net mvc using angularjs. I have the following as my file upload UI.

```
<form name="f1" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="SaveFile()" novalidate>
    <div style="color: red">{{Message}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Select File:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileForUpload(this.files)"
               class="form-control input-bordered" required>                      
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="(f1.file.$dirty || IsFormSubmitted) && f1.file.$error.required">Image required!</span>
        <span class="text-danger">{{ FileInvalidMessage }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="uFileDescription" class="form-control input-bordered {{(IsFormSubmitted?'ng-dirty' + (f1.uFileDescription.$invalid?' ng-invalid' : ''):'')}}" autofocus data-ng-model="FileDescription" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary">Upload File</button>
        <a href="#/FileUpload" class="btn btn--secondary">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The section where the above error is coming from is this:

```
 <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileForUpload(this.files)" class="form-control input-bordered" required>
```

A portion of my controller has this function as a scope variable.

```
      $scope.selectFileForUpload = function (files) {
            $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = file[0];
      }
```

What should I do differently to avoid this error?

Comment: The error mentions that `selectedFileForUpload` is not a function. You are defining a function called `selectFileForUpoad` on your scope. Do you just have a typo on the name of the method?

Comment: @Jacob No I don't have a typo on the name of the method. I followed a tutorial on this and that was how the code was written. I'm using angularjs version 1.6.6 for the project.

Comment: In the error in your title it's `selectedFileForUpload`. In your HTML it's `selectFileForUpload`. In your scope, it's `selectFileForUpoad`. None of those match. It doesn't matter if your tutorial has a typo. It doesn't make the typos any more correct. If the code you posted isn't the actual code and you don't have a typo, you ought to edit the question.

Comment: @Jacob let me update the question then. It should be selectFileForUpload

Comment: @Jacob question has been updated!

Comment: Is your `$scope.selectFileForUpoad` function definition the actual code, or did you forget to update that as well? I ask because `...is not a function` is frequently caused by typos.

Comment: @Jacob yes it's the actual code

Comment: @Jacob are you there?

Comment: @Jacob do I need to add my controller for you to see the function?

Comment: You should never use `angular.element().scope()` in production code. You should use [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) or another method for passing messages between components/directives.

Comment: @Guzzyman: The spelling differs. You have a typo. One is `selectFileForUpoad` and the other is `selectFileForUpload`. You need to fix that. `selectFileForUpload` is not a function because you literally did not define a function with that name.

Comment: @Jacob That's a typo from my end while typing it in here. In the code itself it's correct. Let me correct the code here. I still have the same error though!

Comment: @HereticMonkey so how should I use $emit in this context?

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't here. Here you would just use ngOnChange or use a directive as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/17063000/215552.

Answer (score 0):

```
̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶F̶i̶l̶e̶F̶o̶r̶U̶p̶o̶a̶d̶(̶)̶{̶
$scope.selectFileForUpload = function(files) {
   $scope.SelectFileForUpload = files[0];
}
```

Frankly having a function name and a variable name that differ by the capitilization of one letter is poor programming practice. It makes the code error prone and difficult to read.

---

Instead of using `angular.element(this).scope()`, I recommend using a custom directive that works with the [ng-model controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

```js
app.directive("selectNgFiles", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

#### Usage:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"
       ̶o̶n̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶=̶"̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶)̶.̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶(̶)̶.̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶F̶i̶l̶e̶F̶o̶r̶U̶p̶l̶o̶a̶d̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶f̶i̶l̶e̶s̶)̶"̶
       select-ng-files ng-model="files"
       ng-change="selectFileForUpload(files)"
       class="form-control input-bordered" required>
```

The `.scope()` method of [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods) requires [Debug Data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) to be enabled. Which is not the case with minified versions of AngularJS.

In addition, event handlers invoked with the `onchange` attribute are not integrated with the AngularJS execution context and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

For more information, see [ng-model for `<input type=“file”/>` (with directive DEMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245)

Comment: That was certainly an typo from my end while typing it here. In the actual code itself it reads: 

$scope.selectFileForUpload = function(files) {
   $scope.SelectFileForUpload = files[0];
} and not what is represented here. 

The error remains the same even after making sure there's no typo in my code.