# How to fire button click event when file selected in input file type?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a file `<input />` and a `<button>`, with a click handler assigned to the button.

What I would like to do is to execute the click handler on the submit button when the selected file changes on the file input.

My code currently looks like this:

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe= function(){
         alert("File Submitted!");  
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type = "file">
    <div><button ng-click="clickMe()">Submit</button></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to automatically submit, when a file has been selected?

Comment: You might need a directive. Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file-with-directive-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should find that the logic fired when the submit button is clicked, can instead be automatically invoked when a file is picked on your `<input type="file" />` element by updating your template as follows:

```
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().clickMe(this)">
```

This will cause the `clickMe()` function on the `$scope` object of the enclosing controller `MyController`, to be called. Here's a complete example (with submit button removed seeing it's redundant):

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function() {
      alert("File Submitted!");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().clickMe(this)"> 
  </div>
</body>
```