# Store Image in SQL Using AngularJs and Java?

Tags: java, angularjs, image, file-upload

I'm building a web page for buying and selling used music gear. I'm trying to implement the ability to add a thumbnail image for the item when making a new item posting. I have everything working in terms of sending the items name, price, description, location and contact information to my SQL database and storing the info by converting it to JSON in my AngularJs then sending that to Java/JDBC. I can also retrieve the data and display it on a "current postings" page. However, i'm not sure what to do to send an image with my JSON to my back end to be stored in my DB. I tried adding a BLOB to my Java constructor but it seems that always comes back NULL. Here is some of my code.

My HTML

```
    <form name="insertItem">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Create New Posting</h4>
                <button type="button" ng-click="createItem()"
                    class="btn btn-success">Create Posting</button>
                <p>
                    <span class="text-warning" ng-bind="createStatus"></span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-responive small-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="itemName">Item Name:</label><br> <input
                            id="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                            ng-model="newItem.itemName"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="itemCat">Category:</label><br> <select
                            id="cat" class="form-control"
                            ng-options="value for value in itemCat"
                            ng-model="newItem.itemCat">
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="price">Price $:</label><br> <input
                            type="number" class="form-control" name="price"
                            ng-model="newItem.itemPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="itemDesc">Description:</label><br> <textarea
                                rows="5" id="desc" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="newItem.itemDesc"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="location">Location:</label><br> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="loc"
                            ng-model="newItem.location"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="contact">Contact Info:</label><br> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="cont"
                            ng-model="newItem.contact"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="thumbnail">Upload a Thumbnail Image:
                        </label><br> <input type="file" class="form-control-file border"
                            name="thumbnail" ng-model="newItem.thumbnail"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My AngularJs Post Method

```
musicapp.controller('itemAddController', function($scope, $http ) {         
    $scope.itemCat = ['Guitar', "Bass", "Drums", "Piano", "Keyboard", "Synth", 
        "Microphone", "Classical", "Wind", "Recording", "Software", "Amp/Speaker", "Misc"]

    $scope.createItem = function() {
        $scope.jsonObject = angular.toJson($scope.newItem, false);
        console.log('new item: ' + $scope.jsonObject);              
        $http.post("/MusicApp/API/item", $scope.jsonObject)
        .then(
            function success(response) {                    
                console.log('status: ' + response.status);
                $scope.createStatus = 'Item Posted.';
                $scope.successfulInsert = true;
            },
            function error(response) {
                console.log('error, return status: ' + response.status);
                $scope.createStatus = 'insert error, ' + response.data.message;
            }
        );          
    };
})
```

My Jersey Post

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public List<item> insert(item newItem) { 
        return service.insert(newItem);     
    }
```

My JDBC code

```
private final static String addItems = "INSERT INTO item "
            + "(itemName, itemCat, itemPrice, itemDesc, contact, location, thumbnail) VALUES "
            + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

public List<item> insert(item newItem) {
        List<item> items = new ArrayList<item>();
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
        Connection conn = MariaDbUtil.getConnection();

        try {
            prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(addItems);
            prepStatement.setString(1, newItem.getItemName());
            prepStatement.setString(2, newItem.getItemCat());
            prepStatement.setInt(3, newItem.getItemPrice());
            prepStatement.setString(4, newItem.getItemDesc());
            prepStatement.setString(5, newItem.getContact());
            prepStatement.setString(6, newItem.getLocation());

            prepStatement.setBlob(7, newItem.getThumbnail()); //Blob



            prepStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Row Added " + newItem.getItemName());

            newItem.setItemId(getLastKey(conn));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                    prepStatement.close();
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        items.add(newItem);
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: The core `ng-model` directive does not work with `<input type="file">` out of the box. See [Working Demo of Directive that Works with `ng-model`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not store the thumbnail in the database. I would store the location of where the thumbnail is (path to the actual image).  I would upload the image to S3 or have a location managed by yourself on the server maybe using Samba or something else. This way you could store easily the full image, a thumbnail, and reference both from the database. Then everytime you load the database entry you don't have to load the image and thumbnail with it. Just their locations is enough for the HTML to display them. Then also, in some other scenarios you might find that you want to restrict the image access so then on those image paths you could add some security checks before retrieval etc...

Comment: Would the path to the image be a String?

Comment: It would be indeed. If you were to use AWS S3 for storage you'd have something like: http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/object_path