# File property showing as empty object in request payload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Using AngularJS, I'm making a `post` request to send an array of objects, with each object comprising of string, boolean and object values. The object represents a file uploaded by the user. Before the request, it shows as a file object (`signedPoaDoc`), and after a response, the data shows that a file was included in the reqeust

[image]

We are having issues in the back-end, but the back end developer is saying that the payload in the console is showing no file is being provided, but an empty object for `signedPoaDoc`.

[image]

**html**

```
<form name="validationForm" novalidate>
    <data-ng-init="formData.designatedStates">
        <div data-ng-repeat="states in formData.designatedStates"
              data-ng-init="formData.designatedStates.states;
                            states.signedPoaDoc"> 
            <div>
                <label for="{{states.stateName}}">{{states.stateName}}: </label>
                <div>                   
                    <input type="file" name="{{states.stateName}}"
                           data-ng-model="states.signedPoaDoc" 
                           accept="application/pdf" required>
                </div>

            </div>                          
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function removeCost(item) {
    delete item.validationCost_EUR;
    delete item.validationCost_USD;
    if(!item.signedPoaDoc) { item.signedPoaDoc = null; };
    return item;
}

function submitPoaDocuments(data) {

    var formData = new FormData();

    var designatedMap = data.designatedStates.map(removeCost);
    var extensionMap = data.extensionStates.map(removeCost);
    var validationMap = data.validationStates.map(removeCost);

    formData.append('patentID', patent.patentID);
    formData.append('designatedStates', designatedMap);
    formData.append('extensionStates', extensionMap);
    formData.append('validationStates', validationMap);
    validationService.submitPoas(formData)
    .then(
         function(response){

         }
    )
}
```

As you can see we assigned the `signedPoaDoc` property from the view via `ngModel`.

**Question**

Is this correct that no file is being provided to back end, or is this something to do with chrome and the way they display the payload?

Comment: From the payload no file is being sent. You are more than likely not sending the data correctly. In order to send data and files together in a ajax post request you need to pass a FormData object to the api, eg `XMLHTTPRequest`/`fetch` or whatever library you maybe using. Provide the code you are using to make the request so we can help you better

Comment: @PatrickEvans just updated with code

Comment: The core `ng-model` directive does not work with `<input type="file">` out of the box.

See [How to enable `<input type="file">` to work with ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245)