# Javascript is very slow? When converting image files to base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a basic image upload using this code

```
$scope.fileChanged = function () {
    var fileuploader = angular.element("#uploadFile");   
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var image = document.getElementById("image");
        image.src = reader.result;
        image.style.opacity = 1;
        $scope.image = reader.result; 
    };
    var files = fileuploader[0].files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    fileuploader.trigger('click');
};
```

html

```
<input type="file" ng-show="false" id="uploadFile" accept="image/*"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged()" required>
```

When the user selects a image file, it appears in the HTML and set's `$scope.image`.

Right after the user selects an image, the image is displayed on the HTML `image.src = reader.result;`. Works well and fast.

BUT, `$scope.image = reader.result;` takes like 8 seconds to execute.  Why the image src set is fast but setting a simple string is slow?

Even with few KB image it takes a lot of time..

edit:

// IMAGE APPEARS VERY FAST

```
<img src="../../../assets/img/gamification-icon.png" id="image"
     ng-click="uploadPicture()">
```

// This takes a lot of seconds to appear

```
 <div class="col-md-6">{{image}}</div>
```

Comment: The reason for the slowness is that you try to keep the base64 data in $scope

Comment: @AhmetŞimşek Are you sure it's about that? Then how should I do it then?

Comment: remove this line and try : $scope.image = reader.result;

Comment: Out of interest, why are you setting the event with `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged()"` as if you're accessing the scope from outside of the app? Is there a reason you're not using `ng-change="fileChange()"`?

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias The `ng-model` directive and `ng-change` directives do not work with `<input type="file">` out of the box. See [How to enable `<input type="file">` to work with ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245).

Comment: Ah, `type="file"` of course! Thanks @georgeawg

Answer (score 0):

Data URLs are obsolete because they consume time and memory.

Use Object URLs instead:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
```

Object URLs are much more efficient and faster.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)