# How to add "aria-describedby attribute" to the uib-tooltip automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accessibility, angular-ui-bootstrap

In our application(It's an angularJs), we have "uib-tooltip" in so many places, So I want it to make it a simple piece of code that can automatically add "aria-describedby" attribute to the DOM if "uib-tooltip" is there.

Comment: It is a good idea to show what you have tried, you won't get many favourable responses from people if you only ask how to do something. Have a go and then post some code for us to help you with. At least post a snippet of what a "uib-tooltip" structure would look like in your code for people who don't use angularJS.

Comment: Likely a [custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file-with-directive-demo/43074638#43074638) could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes to the element that has the uib-tooltip directive on it. Just add the "uibTooltip" to a module of yours. This will add additional functionality on top of what the library does.

```
.directive('uibTooltip', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('aria-describedby', 'Whatever text you want.');
    }
  }
})
```