# AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. I am trying to read the uploaded file path from HTML 'file' field whenever a 'change' happens on this field. If i use 'onChange' it works but when i use it angular way using 'ng-change' it doesn't work.

```html
<script>
   var DemoModule = angular.module("Demo",[]);
   DemoModule .controller("form-cntlr",function($scope){
   $scope.selectFile = function()
   {
        $("#file").click();
   }
   $scope.fileNameChaged = function()
   {
        alert("select file");
   }
});
</script>

<div ng-controller="form-cntlr">
    <form>
         <button ng-click="selectFile()">Upload Your File</button>
         <input type="file" style="display:none" 
                          id="file" name='file' ng-Change="fileNameChaged()"/>
    </form>  
</div>
```

**fileNameChaged()** is never calling. Firebug also doesn't show any error.

Comment: Could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17063000/983992

Comment: See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631702/file-pick-with-angular-js

Answer (score 250, accepted):

No binding support for File Upload control

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375

```
<div ng-controller="form-cntlr">
        <form>
             <button ng-click="selectFile()">Upload Your File</button>
             <input type="file" style="display:none" 
                id="file" name='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" />
        </form>  
    </div>
```

instead of

```
 <input type="file" style="display:none" 
    id="file" name='file' ng-Change="fileNameChanged()" />
```

can you try

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" 
    id="file" name='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged()" />
```

> Note: this requires the angular application to always be in [debug mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production). This will not work in production code if debug mode is disabled.

and in your function changes
instead of

```
$scope.fileNameChanged = function() {
   alert("select file");
}
```

can you try

```
$scope.fileNameChanged = function() {
  console.log("select file");
}
```

Below is one working example of file upload with drag drop file upload may be helpful
http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/

**Angular File Upload Information**

URL for AngularJS File Upload in ASP.Net

https://github.com/geersch/AngularJSFileUpload

AngularJs native multi-file upload with progress with NodeJS

http://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/angularjs-native-multi-file-upload-with-progress/

ngUpload - An AngularJS Service for uploading files using iframe

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngUpload

Comment: It worked!!! one more question how can i get the file path from this file input type?

Comment: onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChaged(this)"


 $scope.fileNameChaged = function(element)
   {
    console.log('files:', element.files);
   }
Can you change in two place and check ?
depending on browser you will get the file full path

i have  update the fiddle below is the url
upload file and check console
http://jsfiddle.net/utp7j/260/

Comment: I am using in mozilla and its giving [object FileList]. How will i get the file path

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
                   console.log(element.files[i])
 }

When you loop over the files object in mozilla attribut is "mozFullPath"
if you find my answer useful you can upvote also

Comment: It worked but dont you think its a bit complicated compared to jQuery $("#file").text().

Comment: You are not suppose to do any DOM manipulation in angular controllers, thus $("#file").text() should not be used. The point is angular controllers can be tested without an actual DOM attached to it.

Comment: This method circumvents the default AngularJS processing, so $scope.$digest() isn't called (bindings aren't updated). Call 'angular.element(this).scope().$digest()' afterwards or call a scope method that uses $apply.

Comment: This works, but there is a bug. Say you open the browse dialog (the input box), select multiple files, and retrieve those files in a callback that is listening for an 'onchange'. You will receive that list of files. Now, I have a dialog where the user can delete that list of files and select a new list. If the user selects the same list as before, the 'onchange' event listener is not triggered because the value of the input box did not change! Can I detect an 'onclick' event from the 'Open' button on the browse dialog only?

Comment: I just solved that issue. In the callback of your 'onchange' event listener, make sure that you set the value of your input to "" in order to re-trigger the 'onchange' event next time.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. Calling angular.element(blah).scope() is a debug feature that you should only use for debugging. Angular doesn't use the .scope feature. It is only there to help developers debug. When you build your app and deploy to production, you are supposed to turn debug info off. This speeds up your all A LOT!!! So, to write code that depends on element.scope() calls is a bad idea. Don't do this. The answer about creating a custom directive is the right way to do this. @JQueryGuru you should update your answer. Because it has the most votes, people will follow this bad advice.

Comment: To learn more about turning off debug data to speed up your app, read the Angular production guide. It talks about the speed you gain by turning it off and how to do it: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production

Comment: This solution will break the app when debug info is disabled. Disabling that for production is an official recommendation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production. Please see also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/12/22/exploring-angular-1.3-disabling-debug-info.html

Comment: BAD SOLUTION ...  ... read other comments about 'turning off debugging' ... ... ... and see `sqren`'s solution ... ... ... @0MV1

Comment: Perfect, i try so many things to preform an individual or multiple row selection with the same event, but failed, with that line "onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged()" of creative call I can do easily WHAT I NEED..

Comment: This is a great solution if you don't mind your site being hacked.

Comment: @manish as many pointed out, this answer is very bad... and it can mislead angular beginners. I nearly got fooled too before investigating a little bit. Can you reconsider your accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: These comments address all the flaws with this solution, not to mention it involves placing unnecessary logic in the template. Check out my solution. It is the correct way to handle this situation. Cheers.

Answer (score 494):

I made a small directive to listen for file input changes.

[View JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqren/27ugfym6/)

**view.html:**

```
<input type="file" custom-on-change="uploadFile">
```

**controller.js:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
    };
});
```

**directive.js:**

```
app.directive('customOnChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
      element.on('change', onChangeHandler);
      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        element.off();
      });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This works well if a different file is chosen each time.  Is it possible to listen for when the same file is selected as well?

Comment: This has one very unfortunate "bug" - the controller is not bound as "this" in the customOnChange, but the file input! It threw me off for a long time and I couldn't find the actual bug. I am not yet sure how to actually call it with correctly set "this".

Comment: the fiddle does not work for me, either on Chrome or Firefox, as of today.

Comment: This answer is flawed as stated by @KarelBílek. I couldn't get around it and decided to use angular-file-upload.

Comment: @sqren, second time without selecting any file, if i click on `cancel` button, already selected file name is getting reset to 'No file chosen', can you suggest some way to handle this case.

Comment: @Karel Bílek you can try binding the directives scope with ```element.bind('change', onChangeHandler.bind(scope));```. Be careful here because this will change depending on how you structured your app. I was able to access the 'this' that I needed in my controller which was on the prototype object 'vm'. Hope that helps.

Comment: IE and maybe even Chrome doesn't like when you re-upload a file with the same name.  Here is how to fix that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file#answer-12102992

Comment: This stops working if you select the same file twice from the system prompt.

Comment: To get this to work, i had to implement the changes suggested by @PatrickMichalina and, because the function executes in the directive's isolate scope, also add a `$scope.$apply()` call at the end of the function. It works with multiple selections of the same file with the changes from the fiddle linked by @sqren in his Sept 12 '15 comment.

Comment: Can you also access the files content with this method. I have a file which I only need to upload to the frontend.

Comment: This is a great solution.  But it is missing one bit.  When the input is updated, the form should be marked as dirty.  Add `require: '^form',` to the directive definition, pass the form controller to the link function, then call `form.$setDirty()` in the change handler function.

Comment: What does `restrict: 'A'` do?

Comment: @makz `restrict: 'A'` restricts the directive to be used as attribute name. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive Other values are `E - element, C - class, M - comment` . You can use combination `ACE` which means it can be anywhere in the combination.

Comment: I have some issues with the scope, posted `plnkr` link to the `chat`: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35411481#35411481

Comment: This is absolutely how to do it, worked like a charm. Besides, why would you use a debug feature in production?

Comment: If a file is opened and when we try uploading in the file in Microsoft Edge browser. Nothing is happening. Can you help?

Comment: @shaikh this is the better way. When I left that comment 3 years ago, this answer didn't have the most votes. Now it does, making it look like I was saying that this answer is not good. But, this answer is good. This is how I would do it.

Comment: @KarelBílek I think I had the same issue. Just make sure to set a unique `id` on the input and it should work.

Comment: JS fiddle doesn't work. Shame - it seemed like a short and nice solution...

Comment: I thought it didn't bind this correctly, as @KarelBílek mentioned, but then realized it is binding fine, except the view didn't refresh, so this line helped `element.on('change', (...args) => scope.$apply(() => onChangeHandler(...args)));` I don't know if it is the most ideomatic way doing this

Comment: Works! The input file should be cleared to upload same file multiple times. Like @sqren shows in the fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

This is a refinement of some of the other ones around, the data will end up in an ng-model, which is normally what you want.

Markup (just make an attribute data-file so the directive can find it)

```
<input
    data-file
    id="id_image" name="image"
    ng-model="my_image_model" type="file">
```

JS

```
app.directive('file', function() {
    return {
        require:"ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, el, attrs, ngModel){
            el.bind('change', function(event){
                var files = event.target.files;
                var file = files[0];

                ngModel.$setViewValue(file);
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Is `$scope.$apply();` required? My `ng-change` event still seems to fire without it.

Comment: @row1 you only need to manually fire an apply if you have other angular things that need to know about it *during* that operation.

Answer (score 27):

The clean way is to write your own directive to bind to "change" event.
Just to let you know IE9 does not support FormData so you cannot really get the file object from the change event.

You can use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) library which already supports IE with FileAPI polyfill and simplify the posting the file to the server. It uses a directive to achieve this.

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ng-file-upload.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var $file = $files[i];
      Upload.upload({
        url: 'my/upload/url',
        data: {file: $file}
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      }); 
    }
  }
}];
```

Comment: This example is outdated. Get new one from docs [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#-usage).

Answer (score 26):

I've expanded on @Stuart Axon's idea to add two-way binding for the file input (i.e. allow resetting the input by resetting the model value back to null):

```
app.directive('bindFile', [function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.files[0]);
                $scope.$apply();
            });

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$viewValue;
            }, function (value) {
                if (!value) {
                    el.val("");
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgzojx6s/4/)

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe.

One note , actually `data-ng-click="vm.theFile=''"` works well ,  no need to   write it to  a controller method

Answer (score 21):

Similar to some of the other good answers here, I wrote a directive to solve this problem, but this implementation more closely mirrors the angular way of attaching events.

You can use the directive like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" file-change="yourHandler($event, files)" />
```

As you can see, you can inject the files selected into your event handler, as you would inject an $event object into any ng event handler.

**Javascript**

```
angular
  .module('yourModule')
  .directive('fileChange', ['$parse', function($parse) {

    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        // Get the function provided in the file-change attribute.
        // Note the attribute has become an angular expression,
        // which is what we are parsing. The provided handler is 
        // wrapped up in an outer function (attrHandler) - we'll 
        // call the provided event handler inside the handler()
        // function below.
        var attrHandler = $parse(attrs['fileChange']);

        // This is a wrapper handler which will be attached to the
        // HTML change event.
        var handler = function (e) {

          $scope.$apply(function () {

            // Execute the provided handler in the directive's scope.
            // The files variable will be available for consumption
            // by the event handler.
            attrHandler($scope, { $event: e, files: e.target.files });
          });
        };

        // Attach the handler to the HTML change event 
        element[0].addEventListener('change', handler, false);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: struggled for a couple days with this until i tried your answer. Thanks!

Comment: How could I pass an additional parameter to the `fileChange` expression? I'm using this directive inside an `ng-repeat` and the `$scope` variable passed to `attrHandler` is the same for each record. What's the best solution?

Answer (score 18):

This directive pass the selected files as well:

```
/**
 *File Input - custom call when the file has changed
 */
.directive('onFileChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.onFileChange);

      element.bind('change', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          var files = element[0].files;
          if (files) {
            onChangeHandler(files);
          }
        });
      });

    }
  };
});
```

The HTML, how to use it:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="file" on-file-change="onFilesSelected">
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.onFilesSelected = function(files) {
     console.log("files - " + files);
};
```

Comment: How the $scope.onFilesSelected looks like in your controller?

Comment: If a file is opened and when we try uploading in the file in Microsoft Edge browser. Nothing is happening. Can you help?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with other browsers. i am facing issue in microsoft edge @ingaham

Comment: This is exactly what i needed thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend to create a directive

```
<input type="file" custom-on-change handler="functionToBeCalled(params)">

app.directive('customOnChange', [function() {
        'use strict';

        return {
            restrict: "A",

            scope: {
                handler: '&'
            },
            link: function(scope, element){

                element.change(function(event){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        var params = {event: event, el: element};
                        scope.handler({params: params});
                    });
                });
            }

        };
    }]);
```

this directive can be used many times, it uses its own scope and doesn't depend on parent scope. You can also give some params to handler function. Handler function will be called with scope object, that was active when you changed the input. 
$apply updates your model each time the change event is called

Answer (score 4):

The simplest Angular jqLite version.

JS:

```
.directive('cOnChange', function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope : {
            cOnChange: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('change', function () {
                scope.cOnChange();
        });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" data-c-on-change="your.functionName()">
```

Comment: If a file is opened and when we try uploading in the file in Microsoft Edge browser. Nothing is happening. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

### Working Demo of "files-input" Directive that Works with `ng-change`<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245)</sup>

To make an `<input type=file>` element work the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive, it needs a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that works with the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive.

```
<input type="file" files-input ng-model="fileList" 
       ng-change="onInputChange()" multiple />
```

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
})

.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
     $scope.onInputChange = function() {
         console.log("input change");
     };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h1>AngularJS Input `type=file` Demo</h1>
    
    <input type="file" files-input ng-model="fileList" 
           ng-change="onInputChange()" multiple />
    
    <h2>Files</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="file in fileList">
      {{file.name}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Great but directive is only called once ! If I change file selected then directive is not called a second time ! Do you have any idea about this behavior ?

Comment: The DEMO doesn't have that problem. Create a new question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for readers to examine.

Comment: yes it have that problem the console log "input change" only displays once even if you change selected files many times !

Comment: after testing, it works on chromium but it doesn't on latest firefox version ... damn browser compatibilty !!!

Answer (score 1):

Too complete solution base on:

```
`onchange="angular.element(this).scope().UpLoadFile(this.files)"`
```

A simple way to hide the input field and replace it with a image, here after a solution, that also require a hack on angular but that do the job [TriggerEvent does not work as expected]

The solution:

- place the input-field in display:none [the input field exist in the DOM but is not visible]
- place your image right after 
  On the image use nb-click() to activate a method

When the image is clicked simulate a DOM action 'click' on the input field. Et voilà!

```
 var tmpl = '<input type="file" id="{{name}}-filein"' + 
             'onchange="angular.element(this).scope().UpLoadFile(this.files)"' +
             ' multiple accept="{{mime}}/*" style="display:none" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">'+
             ' <img id="{{name}}-img" src="{{icon}}" ng-click="clicked()">' +
             '';
   // Image was clicked let's simulate an input (file) click
   scope.inputElem = elem.find('input'); // find input in directive
   scope.clicked = function () {
         console.log ('Image clicked');
         scope.inputElem[0].click(); // Warning Angular TriggerEvent does not work!!!
    };
```

Comment: You cannot use angular.element(this).scope(), this is a debug feature!

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting way to listen to file input changes is with a watch over the ng-model attribute of the input file. Of course, FileModel is a custom directive.

Like this:

HTML -> `<input type="file" file-model="change.fnEvidence">`

JS Code ->

```
$scope.$watch('change.fnEvidence', function() {
                    alert("has changed");
                });
```

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this;

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button id="uploadFileButton" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.upload()">    
<span  class="fa fa-paperclip"></span></button>
<input type="file" id="txtUploadFile" name="fileInput" style="display: none;" />
```

```
// self is the instance of $scope or this
self.upload = function () {
   var ctrl = angular.element("#txtUploadFile");
   ctrl.on('change', fileNameChanged);
   ctrl.click();
}

function fileNameChanged(e) {
    console.log(self.currentItem);
    alert("select file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular elements (such as the root element of a directive) are jQuery [Lite] objects. This means we can register the event listener like so:

```
link($scope, $el) {
    const fileInputSelector = '.my-file-input'

    function setFile() {
        // access file via $el.find(fileInputSelector).get(0).files[0]
    }

    $el.on('change', fileInputSelector, setFile)
}
```

This is jQuery event delegation. Here, the listener is attached to the root element of the directive. When the event is triggered, it will bubble up to the registered element and jQuery will determine if the event originated on an inner element matching the defined selector. If it does, the handler will fire.

Benefits of this method are:

- the handler is bound to the $element which will be automatically cleaned up when the directive scope is destroyed.
- no code in the template
- will work even if the target delegate (input) has not yet been rendered when you register the event handler (such as when using `ng-if` or `ng-switch`)

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the below code in onchange and it will detect change. you can write a function on X click or something to remove file data..

```
document.getElementById(id).value = "";
```

Comment: This is bad practice and not angular like.