# Pass a picture from Angualrjs front-end to Laravel back-end

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, image-uploading

I'm building an app in which I need to upload an image with angularjs, pass it with other data to a save() method written in laravel, what is the simplest way to do it?

in my html I have a title field and an image uploader:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" required ng-model="selectedAD.title">                           
          <input type="file" name="file" ngf-max-size="2MB"  required ng-model="selectedAD.image"/>
<a class="btn-portal"  type="submit" ng-click="saveAD()">
</form>
```

and inside my js file, I pass these data into the save route which goes to the store() function in laravel and moves the image into a folder, like this:

```
        $scope.selectedAD = ad;
$scope.saveAD = function(){

    $scope.managementErrors = [];

        adsResource.save($scope.selectedAD,function(success){
            $('#ads-modal').modal('hide');
            showSuccessAlert($scope,$timeout, getSuccessMessages(success),$('#successMessages'));

            $scope.getAdsTimeout();
        },function(error){
            $scope.managementErrors = getErrorMessagesUpdate(error);
        });
```

this way the image is not passed to laravel processing code, it instead passes null to the store function, any helpful guides ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754943/preview-image-before-uploading-angularjs/31952876#31952876.. 

I am not sure.. but if this can help you

Comment: that didn't help, but thank you @SourabhAgrawal

Comment: What I need is to store the uploaded file inside the array ($scope.selectedAD) alongside with other data and then pass them to the save() route @SourabhAgrawal

Comment: @SamJoni Did you solve it?