# How to store an image that has been uploaded.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I store the image that will be uploaded to the input type file into a variable to then be previewed into the DOM? I'm using a MEAN stack if this helps with an answer.

```
            <form method="post">
                <label class="app-file-input button" flow-init>
                    <span>Upload</span>
                    <i class="icon-enter"></i>
                    <input type="file" flow-btn/>
                    <img flow-img="$flow.files[0]" />
                </label>
            </form>
```

I've read once the image has been uploaded it gets stored in a temp storage. How would I access that to then preview the image before uploading?

Cheers

Comment: you may need add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form attributes

Comment: perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it the Angular way... If you are trying to implement your own solution you can use this simple code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952876/407245

However if I were you, I would use something like this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload or https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Comment: Why would you use something like that instead of writing it yourself out of interest?

Answer (score 0):

This is whats i got for you :

Please take a look at the sample JS code below:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}



 $(document ).on('change','#imgInp' , function(){ readURL(this); });
```

and the associated HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/)

[Referal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded#)

Comment: I've seen this answer in another post. I've tried to implement it but when I choose an image it doesn't update the dom. Not even a console.log error. I'm putting the script in my controller. Maybe there is something that is blocking it

Comment: any ideas of why this might be

Comment: on which browser you are trying ?

Comment: Chrome latest. The Demo works may i add, but on my MEAN stack it doesn't work at all

Comment: which stack ? i dint get it

Comment: I'm now getting this error. Cannot read property 'files' of undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: alert input value in readURL function and check if any value is being passed

Comment: TRY  `$(document ).on('change','#imgInp' , function(){  readURL(this); });`

Comment: Thanks Yo Yo, The answer above has been more prudent in this occasion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MaxwellLynn :if this helped than i wont mind if you upvote d answer

Comment: Sorry Yo Yo, It was the other answer that helped me. Thank you for your help