# Setting type="{{value}}" and value = file with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looping through an array called fieldset.fields

Everything works fine, except when it comes to this:

```
type="{{field.type || 'text'}}"
```

most values work, 'like' test and 'asdf' but if i set the the `field.type = file`, and look in the inspector, it says type="text", removing the default attribute(`type="{{field.type}}"`) doesn't help either.

sample array:
                {
                    label: 'First Name',
                    name: 'firstname',
                    key: 'entry.810220554',
                    type: 'text',
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Bild',
                    name: 'image',
                    key: 'entry.810220554',
                    type: 'file',
                    required: true
                },

full template:

```
<div 
        ng-repeat="field in fieldset.fields"
        ng-switch="field.type"
>
        <div class="fieldset" ng-switch-when="radio" class="options">
            <!--radiobuttons-->
            <div class="radiobutton" ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels">
                <input
                    type="radio" 
                    name="{{field['key']}}"
                    value="{{mylabel.name}}" 
                    id="{{mylabel.name}}"
                    ng-model='$parent.my_radio_button'
                    ng-class='{ selected: (my_radio_button == mylabel.name) }'
                >
                <label for="{{mylabel.name}}">
                    {{mylabel.label}}
                </label>
            </div>
         </div>


        <label 
            ng-switch-default
            for="{{field.name}}"
            >                           
            {{field.label}}
        </label>
        <!--text-input-->
        <input
            ng-switch-default
            type="{{field.type || 'text'}}" 
            name="{{field.key}}"  
            id="{{field.name}}" 
            ng-required="field.required"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem in Chrome. Chrome cannot change the input type of a field to 'file' once it's created the element. Changing the type to Checkbox works, file is the only one I found that doesn't work yet..

I put your sample in a plnkr and it works fine in firefox: http://plnkr.co/edit/tCSZDz9xjI2Hla3rNQ97?p=preview

But even if I manually tweak the input type to "file" in chrome devTools, it won't render a file input.

**Solution:**
For now  think your best solution is to actually create the element. This is pretty easy to do using a custom directive. It should be unnecessary but I think that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: I created a bug for this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303117

Comment: And here's another fiddle to show it's not just Angular! http://jsfiddle.net/AHTZH/

Answer (score 0):

According to the selected answer here:

[AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

There is no, or limited, binding support for file. This means that trying to bind to file is likely going to make for problems.