# ng-change on <input type="file"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run my `upload()` function when a file input changes. However, I can't make it work.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="image" ng-change="uploadImage()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.uploadImage = function() {
    console.log('Changed');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

Answer (score 54):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/fA968/

**JS:-**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.uploadImage = function () {
        console.log("Changed");
    }
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="file" ng-model="image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage()" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Pixark Does this answer your question?

Comment: I just ran into this, and your solution works. It's a shame that ng-change doesn't seem to work on file uploads though.

Comment: This works, but how would you pass $event? Just putting $event as a function parameter gives a not defined error.

Comment: This answer should be accepted... but, why must be done this way? `angular.element(this).scope().XXX()` instead of `XXX()` ..Is there a reason beside of just working?

Comment: @sports Since `onchange` is an HTML attribute (instead of an Angular directive) it doesn't know about the functions defined in your controller (under `$scope`) that's why you need to make an explicit reference to the current scope with `angular.element(this).scope()`

Comment: `angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)` and use `function(input){input.files[0] ... }`

Comment: This won't work in except in debug mode; this might be better:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19647381/2056448

Comment: Plus one for teaching me the use of "this" instead of passing the controler name. Thx!

Comment: Also doesn't file a second time if you select the same file again.

Comment: You can get it to fire a second time if you select the same file again by using this `onclick="this.value=null"`, if that's your need.

Comment: This approach is too hackish, a custom directive is more appropriate

Comment: when use this upload on a _forloop_.,how can pass **index** through this `uploadImage()`

Comment: This seems not to be working when debug is false. The scope() is undefined: Here is a thread about this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9515

Answer (score 53):

Here's a directive I made that accomplishes what you are asking. If I'm not mistaken, I think the other solutions won't work in production mode, but this one does.  It is used like so:

```
<input ng-upload-change="fileChanged($event)" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.fileChanged = function($event){
    var files = $event.target.files;
}
```

And for the directive to include somewhere in your code:

```
angular.module("YOUR_APP_NAME").directive("ngUploadChange",function(){
    return{
        scope:{
            ngUploadChange:"&"
        },
        link:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $element.on("change",function(event){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.ngUploadChange({$event: event})
                })
            })
            $scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
                $element.off();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This code is released into the public domain, no attributions required.

You should also be aware that if somebody selects a file, closes the file input, and then selects the same file again later on, it won't fire the change function again.  To fix this, I've created a more complete directive that replaces the input under the hood each time you use it.  I put it on github here:

https://github.com/dtruel/angular-file-input/tree/master

Comment: Someone give this man a medal. So sad I'm the only upvote. Your solution works like a charm. Thanks for that. I think it is more angular than the others.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting way to listen to file input change is with a watch over the ng-model attribute of the input file.

Like this:

HTML -> `<input type="file" file-model="change.fnEvidence">`

JS Code ->

```
$scope.$watch('change.fnEvidence', function() {
                    alert("has changed");
                });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -5):

Use ng-file-select="upload($files)"

```
'<input type="file" class="form-control" ng-model="alunos.file" accept="image/*" ng-file-select="upload($files)"/>'
```

where upload is a function:`$scope.upload = function(file){
    console.log(file);
};`

Comment: I have tried your code in a fiddle but it's not working.