# Pass angularJS $index into onchange

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an input file within a ng-repeat in my angularJS app. I need to pass the $index variable to the onchange attribute. I'm using onchange and not ng-change because I need the uploaded object ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146713/ng-change-on-input-type-file))

In the following code I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $index is not defined'

Jade code sample:

```
div.input-group(ng-repeat='filename in filenames track by $index') 
    input(type='file', onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this.files, **$index**)")
```

Comment: Have you tried `angular.element(this).scope().$index` instead?

Comment: Works like a charm! Please post it as the answer and I'll validate it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `onchange` attribute, the scope is only accessible via `angular.element(this).scope()`. That's the method you use to call the `file_changed()` function, and you should use the same in order to have access to the `$index` attribute:

```
 <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this.files, angular.element(this).scope().$index)" />
```

Notice that this is becoming pretty long! A solution is to simply pass the DOM element to the function, and obtain all the informations from it:

```
 <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" />
```

```
$scope.file_changed = function (element) {
    var index = angular.element(element).scope().$index;
    var files = element.files;

    // …
};
```

Comment: @ncohen I'm pretty sure `var index = $scope.$index;` should perfectly work too. Can you try it?

Comment: @ncohen Inside the `file_changed()` method, I mean. No?

Comment: var index = angular.element(ele).scope().$index; always return 0. any idea pls?

Comment: @beewest A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be necessary to help you. I can only advice you to open a question for your case. Don't hesitate to link to this one to show your research effort.

Comment: I have used the same .in my case I wants to uplaod different file with different rows . Using above solution index always return zero for every row .could you please assist .thank you