# Function is not defined ReferecenError onchange in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, onchange

I'm having issues with onchange event for file input.
Here is my code:

Html:

```
 <input type="file" kendo-upload k-options="uploadOptions" id="fileInput" onchange="fileUploaded(event)"/>
```

Angularjs code - using Typescript.

```
$scope.fileUploaded = (event) => {
            console.log("Testing file upload");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.readFile = reader.result;
                });
            };
            var file = target.files[0];
            reader.readAsText(file);
        };
```

I tried to follow this and change accordingly but am still having issues. 
[Pass angularJS $index into onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983580/pass-angularjs-index-into-onchange)

I changed like this.

```
<input type="file" kendo-upload k-options="uploadOptions" id="fileInput" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileUploaded(this)">
```

I got this error.
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. 
onchange

When I am trying to use ng-change, I have this error.

```
<div kendo-window="importFile" k-visible="false" k-modal="true" k-title="'Import File'"
         k-min-width="450" k-max-width="450"
         k-min-height="418" k-max-height="418">
        <form kendo-validator="validator" ng-submit="validate($event)">
                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    <input type="file" kendo-upload k-options="uploadOptions" id="fileInput" ng-change="fileUploaded($event)"/>
                </li>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This gives error when accessing this
$scope.importFile.center();
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined"
Again, works fine if I use ng-click.

Any help on this is higly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use `ng-change()` angular function rather than `onChange()` plain javascript function.

Comment: Change the input's attribute to `ng-change="fileUploaded($event)"`.

Comment: Thanks Jim and Gaurav! However, I still receive another error when trying to use ng-change. I have updated my post.

Comment: What's that `$scope.importReport` thing? Do you have it somewhere in your code?

Comment: Hi Ammar, my mistake, its $scope.importFile.center(). I changed it. Its a Kendo-window.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `ngChange` in this case since `ngChange` always requires `ngModel` and `ngModel` doesn't work with input type file. Also, you cannot access a function binded to `$scope` directly using `onchange`. Instead use the following:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileUploaded($event)"
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun, I have this error when trying to user the way you suggested. ReferenceError: $event is not defined onchange

Comment: Replace $event with 'this'

Comment: Hi Tarun, thanks for the suggestion but i tried that way earlier. It's in my code above. I got this error. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. onchange

Comment: Is there any way to work arround since in the code I am working in they set something like this :  var _this = this;   and instead of doing $scope.functionName, they do _this.functioName.  So when I use this method, it return an error. Any clues?