# Calling a function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an `<input type="file">` in ng-repeat and  I want to call a function whenever the value of element changes for the `<input type="file">` element in ng-repeat.

I tried calling a `$(#"id").change()` function but it is not working. I have tried using ng-change, but ng-repeat doesnt work when I use ng-change. This is my code:

**IN HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input  type="file" accept="image/*" id="add_{{$index}}"/>
</div>
```

**IN JS**

```
$("#add_images").change(function() {
    alert("HI");
}
```

Comment: You can use `ng-change=""` or need to use event delegation..

Comment: Also ID of an element must be unque.. so an static id in a loop is not a valid html

Comment: @ArunPJohny what if the id is unique.

Comment: @ArunPJohny <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input  type="file" accept="image/*" id="add_{{index}}"/>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

Why you are mixing Angular and JQuery?

You have everything in Angular which you can use it easily!

**In HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input  type="file" accept="image/*" id="add_images" ng-change="doSomething()"/>
</div>
```

**In controller JS**

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
  //do whatever you want to
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't support ng-change for input type=file [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375)

but there are ways to trigger methods on the scope see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs11v0vw/6/)

```html
<div>
  <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <pre>{{items | json }}</pre>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="file" onchange='angular.element(this).scope().onchange(this)' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['test', 'test2'];
    $scope.onchange = function(that) {
      alert(that.value)
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are repeating id inside ng-repeat. Id should be unique. I will suggest you to use.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input  type="file" accept="image/*" />
</div>
```

$index is the index of item.

Second use onchange function of Javascript

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input  type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().myFunc()" id="add_images_$index"/>
</div>
```

Attach function to scope

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
  alert("Hi");
}
```

Also refer [ng-change on <input type="file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146713/ng-change-on-input-type-file) if you are trying to catch ng-change on input type file element.

Comment: @murali  I have tried what u said,but ng-repeat is not working when I use ng-change

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MyCtrl'>    
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="file" ng-change="functionName()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.functionName= function() {
     alert("hi your call worked successfully");
     }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use directive which is much better and cleaner.

HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input  type="file" accept="image/*" id="add_{{$index}}" dir-change/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
directive('dirChange',function(){

  return {
    link : function(scope,ele){ 

      ele.bind('change',function(){ 
          //code

      });
    }
  }

})
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmMRZpkNGHaTLRJPYAX3?p=preview)