# using angular.element(bar).scope().foo() with "this" as constroller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this controller:

```
function controller(chatService,userService) {
        const vm = this;
        vm.postPhoto = postPhoto;

        function postPhoto(files) {
            console.log(files);
        }
    }
```

this is where i want to acess the function postPhoto to get the files and post to the server:

```
       <input type="file" id="image_uploads"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().postPhoto(this.files)"
       style="display:none;" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
```

and i got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postPhoto' of undefined

everything works when i use "$scope" instead of "this" but i am asking how or if i can do that without changing the way i do scope..besides ng-change doesnt work on upload files

Comment: In case I am missing something, why are you not doing this 'the angular' way, e.g. `ng-change`? It is for this exact use case. You can change the `onchange` line to `ng-change="postPhoto(this.files)"`.

Comment: i test here and it doesnt work on input with type=file, because of that i am trying "onchange", maybe i can do a directive, what do you think?

Comment: I see, I did a quick search and found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41557378/4606706), which uses a directive to handle this the angular way. I would recommend trying it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function controller(chatService,userService) {
        var vm = this;
        function postPhoto(files) {
            console.log(files);
        }
        vm.postPhoto = postPhoto;
    }
```