# Alternative for (change) listener?

Tags: angular, typescript, listener, event-listener

So I want to make a webpage where i can upload an excel(xlsx) file then display its data to the page. I was able to achieve this by using the xlsx library. But the problem now is if I upload an excel file, then edit its data through ms excel, then upload it again on the page, the edits that I made on the file won't display on the page. It still displays the data that when I didn't edit the file yet.
Here is my code for my component .ts

```
data: AOA = [ [], [] ];     
reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    onFileChange(evt: any) {
        //this._router.navigate(['']);
        /* wire up file reader */
        console.log('HERE');
        const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
        if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
        this.reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        /* read workbook */
        this.data = [ [], [] ];
        console.log(this.data);
        const bstr: string  = e.target.result;
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
        /* grab first sheet */
        const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        /* save data */
        this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));
        console.log(this.data);
        }
        this.reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    }
```

and here's my code for displaying the data in my component.html

```
<div>
  <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" name="fileUploaded" value="Choose a File" accept=".xlsx, .xls">
  <br>
  <table class="sjs-table table table-striped">
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
        <td *ngFor="let val of row">
          {{val}}
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input (click)="export()" type="submit" id="exportButton" value="Export">
</div>
```

I tried debugging it and found out that the problem is the (change) listener. It will not execute the onFileChange($event) unless the file the I uploaded is really changed. I tried researching alternatives for the change listener but I didn't found anything. Do you guys know an alternative to this? Or what can you suggest I do? Should I change the way I upload the file?

I'm currently using Angular CLI: 1.7.4; Node: 8.11.1; Typescritp: 2.8.1 Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Look at this post and have a look at the second answer by user3413723: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146713/ng-change-on-input-type-file

Comment: I looked at it and he was using angularJS. I'm using angular4. I believe those two are different and when I tried using it on my code it gave me erros.