# Which event to get multiple file selected at single input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

So far i get the file(single file) from single input using

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {

            $scope.$apply(function () {            


                $scope.files.push(args.file);
            });
        });
```

I wonder if i use "multiple" file input, can i still get file"s" with event "fileSelected"???

```
<input type='file' id='tempFiles' multiple></input>
```

An if i can, can i do something like

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
                                    $scope.$apply(function () {            


                $scope.files.push(args.files);
            });         });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Daniel Afarid's Angular File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Controller

```
$scope.selectedFiles = [];
$scope.dataUrls = [];
$scope.model = 'test model';

$scope.onImageSelect = function($files) {

    $scope.selectedFiles['image'] = $files[0];


    var $file = $files[0];
    if (window.FileReader && $file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL($files[0]);

        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        $timeout(function() {
        $scope.dataUrls['image'] = e.target.result;
            });
        }
    }    

}

$scope.save_image =  function(){

        $upload.upload({
                 data:$scope.model
                  url: 'the/url',
                  file: $scope.selectedFiles['image']

        }).then(//success and error callbacks);


    }
```

View

```
                                     <input type="file" ng-file-select="onImageSelect($files)">
                                <br />
                                <img ng-show="dataUrls['image']" ng-src="{{dataUrls['image']}}">
```

Comment: i did not ask how can i realise and upoad images, i asked, how can i upload multiple images?

Comment: @mervellous Just create a <input type="file" multiple>

Comment: thanks, can i ask do i have to use ng-file-select, instead can i do:  <input type=file multiple ng-model="myobject"> , in js $scope.myobject.on(fileSelectedOrSOmeOtherEventName)

Comment: That won't work as there is no support for binding in input[type=file]
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375

Comment: sorry action did not work. the work is ugly but worked here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields