# Angularjs binding not working on array of complex object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this controller:

```
 angular.module("upload.app").controller("upload",[upload]);

 function upload(){
    var me = this;

     me.uploadList = [{Name: "Test Upload",
                       Id: 1,
                       NewFiles: []
                     }];
     me.selectedUpload = me.uploadList[0];
     me.setSelected = function(upload) {
        me.selectedUpload = upload;
     }
     ...
     me.addFilesToUpload = function(element){
        me.selectedUpload.NewFiles = element.files;
     }
```

and this html:

```
   <div ng-controller="upload as vm">
       <input id="filechooser" type="file" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().vm.addFilesToUpload(this)" />
       <table>
          <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="up in vm.uploadList" ng-click="vm.setSelected(up)">
                 <td>{{up.Name}}<br />{{up.NewFiles.length}}</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>

       <table>
           <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="file in vm.selectedUpload.NewFiles">
                 <td>{{file.name}}</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

I would expect that when the input onchange event calls `addFilesToUpload()` and the files are then added to the `NewFiles` property, that Angularjs would automatically update the view ... in this case, `{{up.NewFiles.length}}` value in the first table and the second table that lists the files.

However, nothing is being updated until I click on my row in the first table which, as you can see, fires the setSelected function on my controller.

How can I get Angular to refresh when the `NewFiles` property is changed as well?

**Sorry, just fixed the fiddle -- forgot to save it originally**
See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2857/).  Begin by clicking on the Test Upload.  Now select files.  Nothing happens.  Click again on Test Upload and you'll see all the bindings refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$apply` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2858/)):

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.selectedUpload.NewFiles = element.files;
});
```

This is usually done by angular but because you are using the native js event `onchange` you have to wrap it in an `$apply` callback yourself.

Comment: Thanks Marcel.  BTW, if you look at the code I included in this post above, I used a different pattern than what I used in jsFiddle ... I don't inject scope.  Is there a way to use apply without $scope or will I have to pass $scope in to my controller?

Comment: `.controller('upload',['$scope', upload]);` and `function upload($scope){` should work for that one...

Answer (score 0):

There is no default binding provided by angular to input `type=file` https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375, so you'll probably need to create your own directive or you can use [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) library.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields) from stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not actually binding to input type=file.  The question is in regards to the other bindings on my table elements that are bound to properties on my controller.  See my jsFiddle.

Comment: yes, but onchange="angular.element(this).scope().vm.addFilesToUpload(this)"  method has a binding to input type=file

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your updated fiddle is mainly this line

```
$scope.selectedUpload = null;
```

The moment you have selected the files and invoke the callback `addFilesToUpload()`, and assign the selected files to `$scope.selectedUpload.NewFiles = element.files;` then you'll definitely get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'NewFiles' of null

Simply change it back to your original code: `$scope.selectedUpload = $scope.uploadList[0];`

The next problem would be to update the current selected upload list, simply use `$scope.$apply()`, because you are using a native event `onchange` to update the `$scope`. Your callback should look this:

```
 $scope.addFilesToUpload = function(element){
     $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.selectedUpload.NewFiles = element.files;     
     });
 }
```

Check this updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/HB7LU/2861/)**.