# AngularJS ng-change not responding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I want to upload a file to my server, but I want the trigger to be an image.  I constructed an example to test the base functionality, but it isn't responding the way I was expecting.  The window launches properly, but I will eventually want to fire the code in a function after the file has been selected, and I can't get the function in the controller to fire from ng-change.

```
HTML:
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="choose_file">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Landscape_in_the_Adirondacks_Frederic_Edwin_Church.jpg" style="height: 300px; width: 400px"></img>
        <input ng-model="someRandomValue" type="file" ng-change="trigger()" />
    </div>
</div>


Controller:
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.trigger = function() {
        alert("Changed");
    };
});
```

I don't see any issues in the logic, but the alert never pops up.  See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WAxu/) for full code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

Comment: @lucuma Foiled by the AngularDocs again.  Thank you for linking to this answer.