# how to catch ngchange event in a file input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, onchange, fileapi

I have a file input

`<input type="file" ng-change="action()">`

Now in my controller I dont want to do selectors and stuff. so I just have

```
$scope.action = () -> 
  ...
```

However, I want a certain behavior such that as long as user selects a File the $scope.action is called, instead of onchange is there onselect event in angular?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: How to check for changes in file input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields)

Comment: not quite the fix I was hoping for, but onchange is a better way as ng-change listens for the model. either way clearing this input is a must, it seems like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use thisss

```
<input ng-model="photo"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"
       type="file" accept="image/*" />


$scope.file_changed = function(element, $scope) {

     $scope.$apply(function(scope) {

     });
});
```

Comment: the actualy resolution i got was to use document.select(input).text = "" to reset the content.

Comment: This is a bad way to do it, see explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields#comment43502160_17923521