# Displaying files list using AngularJS and input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display a list of files which the user selects using the input[type=file].

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UploadFilesCtrl">
        <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFiles(this)" multiple />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in filenames">
                {{name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="test()">PRINT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('UploadFilesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.uploadFiles = function(element){

        var files = element.files;
        var filenames=[];

        for (i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            filenames.push(files[i].name);
        }


        $scope.files = files;
        $scope.filenames = filenames;   
        console.log(files, filenames);
    };


    $scope.test = function(){
        console.log($scope.files, $scope.filenames);
    }
}]);
```

From some reason the list never gets updated.

The `filenames` and `files` variables in the `$scope` never get updated outside of the `uploadFiles` function (When I click the PRINT button after selecting file I get *undefined*).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `angular.element(this).scope().uploadFiles(this)` I would imagine this isn't causing an angular digest. This seems like a job for a `directive` instead, but in the mean time you can try `$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.files = files; });` to see if it is actually a digest issue

Comment: I just found the answer you got this snippet from. You should [read the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922557/angularjs-how-to-check-for-changes-in-file-input-fields#comment-36734902) before assuming the accepted answer is correct :)

Comment: did you got any error?

Comment: ``$scope.apply`` doesn't do the job from some reason. I ended up trying to create a directive. Thanks!

Comment: This Work Fine in Crome and IE but not work in Firefox in firefox it give error like TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).uploadFiles is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Use `$scope.$apply()` to update your `$scope` objects

```
...
$scope.files = files;
$scope.filenames = filenames;   
$scope.$apply();
console.log(files, filenames);
...
```

Rest is working fine.

**EDIT:**

*RGraham* is correct. This is not a full proof solution. You should use directive instead. But just for a work around you can do a check if `digest` is in progress like this :

```
if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

**Updated fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/HB7LU/13086/

Comment: That's not a very good solution. It's fine for debugging, but OP should switch to using a directive where they don't need `$scope.$apply`. Your code will cause an error if a digest is already in progress.

Answer (score 2):

***You don't need $scope.$apply()***

...............................................................................................................................................................

Your codes are looking very nice. and it's should be working if you did my below thing.

But you have missed only one thing. but that's main thing.

I think you may be got this below error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

please verify in your browser console window, if you got this error,then Please try this

`app = angular.module('myApp',[]);`

instead of

`app = angular.module('myApp');`

You have missed  empty sub models in main model`('myApp',[]);`

All other  codes looks well.

### Update :

Please see this [fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13087/) , Now your selected files names are displayed when you click print button.

Comment: @ameshrajendran I didn't downvoted this, but your answer is not correct? You understood it wrong, I think OP has done it..

Comment: @RameshRajendran. -1 , your very first line is not the answer to OP's question.

Comment: The first line not for OP, that's for @Sourabh- answer

Comment: @RameshRajendran. You can do that in comments. Anyways removed the downvote. :)