# Angular: Pass arguments from Directive to event/expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that, when enter is pressed, an event or expression is fired. I want to pass the element value to the event or expression as seen by my attempt: `{ 'myArg': element.val() }`

The directive works and my event is called, but the parameter is undefined.

What am I missing or what do I need to fix?

```
app.directive('schdKeyenter', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {

            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.$eval(attrs.schdKeyenter, { 'someArg': element.val() });
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" schd-keyenter="onEnterPressed(someArg)">
```

When onEnterPressed() is called, someArg is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of looking, I finally found an example that cleared the way.  I didn't know about the $parse, which makes it all possible.  There might be another way to do this but for now this is my solution.

```
app.directive('schdKeyenter', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

  return function (scope, element, attr) {

    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {

            var attrHandler = $parse(attr['schdKeyenter'])

            scope.$apply(function () {
                attrHandler(scope, { $event: event, $value: element.val() });
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
  }
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" schd-keyenter="onEnterPressed($event, $value)">
```

The example that I built this from was here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26591042/3701159.